# What does git "updating currently checked out branch" warning mean?

Tags: git

When I do a git push, I see the following:

```
warning: updating the currently checked out branch; this may cause confusion,
as the index and working tree do not reflect changes that are now in HEAD.
```

I Googled for this message, and all I can find is a [git mailing list discussion](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/107814) where the authors try to decide exactly how to make this message better to communicate to me what the real problem is.

How did I cause this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push error '\[remote rejected\] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked)

Comment: @WilliamTate no, this post deals with a warning, linked post deals with error

Comment: Yes it is, I think it's the warning you received instead of the error in previous versions of Git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this Git warning message when pushing changes to a remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804545/what-is-this-git-warning-message-when-pushing-changes-to-a-remote-repository)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This happens when you are pushing to a non-bare repo. A bare repo is one that consists solely of a `.git` directory; a non-bare repo also includes a checkout. In general, you should not push to a non-bare repo; in fact, in future version of git, that will be forbidden. If you push to a non-bare repo, then the HEAD of that repo will be out of sync with the index and the working copy.

If you're creating a repo that people are going to want to push to, then you should create it using `git init --bare` (and `git init --bare --shared` if several user accounts need access to it), or `git clone --bare` if you're creating it by cloning an existing repo.

Comment: Thank you.  This important warning was telling me that I was cloned from and pushing to the wrong repository!!  I have a bare repository, similarly named to another repository which I accidentally cloned!

Comment: Is it okay to pull from a non-bare repository to a non-bare. I guess not?

Comment: @Keyo Yes, it's fine to pull from one non-bare repo to another. But you shouldn't push into a non-bare repo.

Comment: Actually, you can push to a non-bare repository just fine, you just can't push to the one branch that is **currently checked out**.

Comment: @Nowhereman This is true, my answer is a bit of a simplification. In general, pushing to a non-bare repo is discouraged, even if only pushing to the currently checkout out branch would actually break anything. If you find yourself pushing to a non-bare repo, it probably means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen it discouraged, and I know of several perfectly valid workflows with Git that involve pushing to a non-bare repo. For example, I routinely version palintext notes with git, one repo on my laptop and one on my workstation. On each computer, a different branch is checked out so I can safely push it to the other computer, where I'll merge (I usually try to only do fast-forwards or I rebase).

Answer (score 12):

In short, your remote repository is no longer a bare one, and you pushing on the remote checkout branch.

See "[How to publish a Git repository](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2007/09/how-to-publish-git-repository.html)":

> A bare repository is one without a checked out working copy of the code. It only contains the git database.
>   As a general rule you should never push into a repository that contains changes in the working copy.
>   To ensure this doesn't happen, we're making the server repository a bare repository - it has no working copy

From [here](http://lists.zerezo.com/git/msg554329.html):

Note that the target of a "push" is normally a **bare** repository (i.e., with no work tree of its own).
You can also push to a repository that has a checked-out working tree, but the working tree
 will not be updated by the push.
This may lead to unexpected results if the branch you push to is the currently checked-out branch.

If a detached work tree is defined (which can for instance correspond to a web server's DocumentRoot), you need to :

- have a `post-receive` hook on your remote repository ([like the one described here](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)), running "`git checkout -f`" and
- [ignore the warning message](http://www.mail-archive.com/frugalware-devel@frugalware.org/msg04465.html) (`git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore`)

Check, on your remote repository, the value of `git config core.worktree` and `git config core.bare`

Comment: Note to self: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041823/2041865#2041865 for an example of bare repo usage.

Answer (score 5):

I made my repository bare by cloning a new, bare, repository from my messed up one, saving the messed-up one just in case, and replacing it with my cloned bare one.

I'm new to git, and when I set up the repsitory, I forgot to use the --bare option. Thanks for all your help!

I've since read the O'Reilly git book and now am a total git convert.