# Local sharing of a Xcode project with git

Tags: xcode, git, local

I have a few Xcode projects on my iMac for which I enabled git when I created the project in Xcode.  Now how can I access the repository from another Mac on my local network and make changes that are then recognized by the repository and propagated when I open the project again on the iMac?

Answer (score 2):

If you've got `remote login` enabled in `System Preferences -> Sharing`, you can access your iMac from your local network via `ssh`, ie `ssh user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`, where `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is your IP address.

You'd want to `git clone` the repository so that you have two copies of it, one on your `iMac` and one on your `OtherMac`. To do that, on `OtherMac`:

```
git clone user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/Users/<USERNAME>/path-to-XCodeProject myProject
```

This will create a folder "myProject" on `OtherMac`, containing a clone of the git repository from `iMac`. Then you'd work, `git commit` as normal on `OtherMac`.

The difficulty you *will* face with this is that the git repository on `iMac` is not `bare`. To get around that, you can [work on specific branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/push-to-non-bare-repository), or set up an intermediate `bare` repository on either Mac, which you then `git push` to from `OtherMac` and `git pull` from from `iMac` (and vice-versa).

I haven't done this; you *might* have issues with Mac-specific XCode project settings. I know they're by default added to the git repository.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  BTW, is that double user@user@ in your git command above correct?

Comment: @Koen Nope, the double `user@user@` shouldn't be there. My bad, will edit accordingly.

Comment: I ended up using DropBox to share my project between the two Macs. To keep everyting in place, I use a symlink (not an alias) to my project folders from the DropBox folder so everthing can stay in place.