# GIT workflow troubles

Tags: git, version-control, github, workflow

My company has a boilerplate theme we use as a starting point for each project hosted on github. Here's what im stuck on at the moment:

1. `git clone [github url]` onto staging server
2. `git clone [staging url]` onto local machine
3. make changes locally
4. git commit/push (using smartGit on local machine)

changes to the file dont appear on staging server

if i run 'git status' on staging server, i can see the file is 'modified' but i dont want to push that to my github. i want this code to be publicly visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you might see is that you're [pushing to a non-bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764793/11343). This means that the staging repository has a working copy, since you cloned it from another one, and Git disallow pushing changes to the current branch of remote repository that has a working copy.

This should have raised an error from `git push` operation, maybe you didn't pay attention to it?

To fix this, you'll want to [change the staging repo to a bare one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2199897/11343), and [checkout the working copy to a different location on the server](http://caiustheory.com/automatically-deploying-website-from-remote-git-repository).

You can also look at deployment tools such as [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp). See also [this page](http://gitolite.com/the-list-and-irc/deploy.html).

Comment: Yeah, i was suppressing errors, thanks for the links. The caius theory article is very helpful.

Comment: Glad to have helped, thanks for accepting the answer! you can also upvote btw

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" i first have to earn the right to vote

Comment: @ryan-inverseparadox: Oh I thought you could still upvote on answers to your own questions...