# How to synchronize two substations with Git?

Tags: php, git, laravel

How to synchronize two substations with Git?
For example,there are two substations:

aaa.domainname.com
bbb.domainname.com

Two substations have the same controller code, they are in respective Controller folders.
In local computer, controller code is in corresponding Controller folder.
So,there is one Controller folder in local computer,and,
there are two Controller folders in Server computer.

How to synchronize local computer's Controller folder to Server's two Controller folders together via Git?

Answer (score 1):

You could in theory:

- [add multiple push urls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/6309)
- [push to non-bare repo on the two servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28381311/6309) (in one git push), provided:

  - the git one those server is 2.3+,
  - `receive.denyCurrentBranch` is set to `updateInstead` on those servers.