# Git: move folder on post-receive

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu

Is it possible to move/rename a folder in a post-receive (or any other hook) on a bare repository?

```
#!/bin/sh
mv /path/to/worktree/src /path/to/worktree/public
```

When I try to push to the repository I get an error:

```
remote: mv: cannot stat `/path/to/worktree/src': No such file or directory
```

I am sure that the folder exists in my local branch.

Comment: Bare repository doesn't have a workdir, that's why it's called "bare".

Comment: Oh, yeah of course. Later in `post-receive` I am calling `git --work-tree=/path/to/worktree/ --git-dir=/path/to/repo/ checkout -f master`. So, perhaps it's just a matter of calling `mv` right after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Later in post-receive I am calling `git --work-tree=/path/to/worktree/ --git-dir=/path/to/repo/ checkout -f master`
>   So, perhaps it's just a matter of calling `mv` right after.

Exactly: right after, *and* in an actual worktree (`/path/to/worktree/`) instead of the current **[bare repo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sitaramc/sitaramc.github.com/blob/dce410b2a2804723676db9cabd7bb506b6d9ba05/concepts/bare.html)**. Any action on files needs to be done in a checked out repo instead of a bare repo.

The other approach would be to [push directly to a non-bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672828/6309), but your approach is safer (first updating a bare repo, then checkout/update elsewhere).