# GIT add production server

Tags: git

I have a production server where I work without using GIT, I have the files on my PC and upload updates with filezilla.

I discovered git and I would use it as a replacement for filezilla.

I already configured git on the PC and I did a push of all the project files in the repository, now I do not know what to do to configure updates on the production server.

Comment: Try to clone your remote repository on the production server with SSH access.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy way is to define a bare repo on your server and push to that **[bare repo](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)**, combined with a post-receive hook to checkout the received files in the folder of your choice/

But with Git 2.3+, if you want, you can:

- initialize a repo directly on the target folder in your server,
- add and commit everything
- set:

  ```
  git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
  ```
- clone that repo on your local PC.
  I assume you can use the same ssh access you must have set in filezilla:

  ```
  git clone user@server:/path/to/git/repo
  ```
- make new commits,
- [push directly to a non-bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672828/6309)

Comment: you mean to push the files to the repository from the production server instead from my pc and then clone from repository to my pc...right?

Comment: Yes, but once cloned on your PC, you can work and push back from your PC.