# Can we "stash" a git rebase in progress

Tags: git, git-rebase

Currently being in the process to `git rebase` a branch into an other (which needs some adaptations and much of time), we need to do a hotfix on production (an other branch).

Is there a way to :

1. Checkout that production branch without loosing all the work done in this rebase process?
2. Do the job on production branch + commit
3. jump back to that rebase process to be completed?

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in way to do this.  You will have to manually back up `.git/rebase-apply` and `.git/ORIG_HEAD` and possibly other internal files, then abort the rebase to work on the other branch, then put the file you backed up back into place.  It will be easier to simply clone the repo and do the hotfix on the clone, or to back up the whole repo before aborting the rebase.

Comment: That matches I guess the answer I gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I left the project as is and did a `git clone` of it to an other folder. I'll code and commit the hotfix into the production branch of that new folder and will push them back to the original project folder when ready.

Comment: There are some caveats with pushing to a non-bare repository, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1764380/279627

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  Some items, such as the index, the `HEAD`, and the in-progress rebase information, are stored in or associated with the work-tree.

You can, as you suggested in your own answer, make a new clone; or, with Git versions 2.6 or above, use `git worktree add`.  (The `git worktree` feature appears in 2.5 but there was a brief rush of fixes followed by a longer trickle of smaller fixes, so this works best in the latest Git versions.)

What `git worktree add` does is create additional work-trees using the existing repository.  This is similar to making a new clone, except that the underlying `.git` repository is shared directly.  Each added work-tree has its own separate index, so instead of *the* index for *the* work-tree, you now have *an* index *per* work-tree.  Instead of *the* `HEAD`, you have one `HEAD` per work-tree, and so on.

There is one hard restriction on `git worktree add`: each work-tree must be in a separate branch.  So if your main work-tree, the one you are in the middle of rebasing, is on branch `develop`, your added work-tree cannot also be on branch `develop`.  If you want or need that, go ahead and use a separate clone.  (You never actually *need* it but the details on this get tricky.)