# How to update a git clone --mirror?

Tags: git, mirror, git-clone, git-remote, git-fetch

I have created a git repository to mirror a live site (which is a non-bare git repository):

```
git clone --mirror ssh://user@example.com/path/to/repo
```

Now, to keep this mirror clone updated with all changes from its remote origin, which command or commands I must use?

I'd like to keep everything updated: commits, refs, hooks, branches, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 260, accepted):

This is the command that you need to execute on the mirror:

```
git remote update
```

Comment: @Magnus Skog: Great. Thanks! Is this all? Do I need another commmand, like `git fetch`? Or `git remote update` alone will do it all?

Comment: I'd like to know too what the difference to git fetch is.

Comment: @Thorbjörn (you'll have to do with a swedish ö :)): Git fetch just updates your repository with remote references from the remote. This command updates _everything_ on the mirrored repository.

Comment: Here's a good answer that explains more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare

Comment: @Thorbjörn: Good question. I have been using a simple "git fetch". I created the question because: 1) After reading something it seemed to me that maybe I am losing information doing this simple way. 2) I want to clone/mirror the hooks!

Comment: @Magnus Skog: That's great! It seems the answer is indeed that simple - as it should be. I am only a bit "sad" that I wanted to mirror also **the hooks**, but it seems that they are not considered part of the "controlled source" of the "source control"...

Comment: Yup, hooks is a completely different story. For good and bad.

Comment: 'git remote update --prune' will do all this, but remove branches when they are removed from the original repository.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding commits, refs, branches and "*et cetera*", Magnus answer just works (`git remote update`).

But unfortunately there is no way to `clone` / mirror / `update` **the hooks**, as I wanted...

I have found this very interesting thread about cloning/mirroring the hooks:

http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/8/28/256180/thread

I learned:

- The hooks are not considered part of the repository contents.
- There is more data, like the `.git/description` folder, which does not get cloned, just as the hooks.
- The default hooks that appear in the `hooks` dir comes from the `TEMPLATE_DIR`
- There is this interesting `template` feature on git.

So, I may either ignore this "clone the hooks thing", or go for a `rsync` strategy, given the purposes of my mirror (backup + source for other clones, only).

Well... I will just forget about hooks cloning, and stick to the `git remote update` way.

- Sehe has just pointed out that not only "hooks" aren't managed by the `clone` / `update` process, but also stashes, rerere, etc... So, for a strict backup, `rsync` or equivalent would really be the way to go. As this is not really necessary in my case (I can afford not having hooks, stashes, and so on), like I said, I will stick to the `remote update`.

Thanks! Improved a bit of my own "git-fu"... :-)

Answer (score 5):

See here: [Git doesn't clone all branches on subsequent clones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563349/git-doesnt-clone-all-branches-on-subsequent-clones/5563660#5563660)

If you really want this by pulling branches instead of `push --mirror`, you can have a look here:

["fetch --all" in a git bare repository doesn't synchronize local branches to the remote ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559321/fetch-all-in-a-git-bare-repository-doesnt-synchronize-local-branches-to-the/5559586#5559586)

This answer provides detailed steps on how to achieve that relatively easily:

Comment: `push` is not an option for me because I need to do it at the receiving side (from where the clone is); `pull` is also not an option because a mirror repository is a bare repository (no working tree, thus no "pull") - it seems that `git remote update` indeed does it all (much easier than the referenced answer)... Anyway, thanks! Certainly there is valuable information in the linked questions/answers.

Comment: ok, I meant pulling as in the usual parlance. Push and pull technology. There's hardly another word except the nonsensical 'get the data from a remote actively at the client' that would not dub a word that has meaning to git or DVCS systems :) The second link will provide the details you want. Note, that 'git remote update' does _not_ in fact maintain the 'mirror' status without the extra operations mentioned there

Comment: hmm... sorry (HTH) - it seems an "absolute" mirror is more easily achieved through a simple "rsync" of the original repo folder... not what I wanted, but.. I just did some tests... and nothing seems to copy the hooks - which I am particularly interested in...

Comment: FYI, the purposes of this mirror are these, only: 1) complete backup from where I can restore if the data at original repo server is lost; 2) somewhere from where others can clone from and get a local working repo, without having any access to the original source repo

Comment: If you want hooks and everything, gitosis might (don't remember well) have what you need, but I'd go with `rsync` in that case. Also, I assume you are forgetting about stashes (see **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository/5248758#5248758)**)  and rerere information too...?