# How can I keep a git mirror in sync (including deleting branches)?

Tags: git, synchronization, mirror

I've cloned a git repo using `git clone --mirror`, and I'd like to keep the mirror up to date.  So far, I've been using `git fetch --all`, but I've noticed that branches deleted in the original repo are not deleted in the mirrored repo.  I've looked at [How to update a `git clone --mirror`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150188/how-to-update-a-git-clone-mirror) but my attempt at using `git remote update` didn't appear to work - branches that were deleted in the original repo are still visible in the mirrored repo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`git remote prune remoteName`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-remote.html) to remove the remote branches.

You can also add the `--prune` tag to `git remote update`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! FYI, the message is not clear, but it does exactly what's asked in the question: it removes local references that are not present anymore on the remote side

Comment: @Andy does update keep my changes or does it overwrite something?

Comment: update shouldn't change any commits on your computer.  all it does is fetch new updates for branches on your remote repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I go one step further and configure it globally:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```