# Remote Respositories backup script for Git

Tags: git

I have moved my source control on git,and now i want to take the backup of my remote repository on a regular basis. Can anyone help me with the batch script for taking the backup of Remote repositories on GIT??

Comment: Please, clarify what you have tried and what problems you have with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created your repository as `git init --bare` - All you need to do to backup it, is to regularly backup that directory. Same way you backup any other directory.

Alternatively, you can create a script that  clones the repository every X time to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

Often a backup of a git repository is simply another git repository. You can set it up initially using `git clone --mirror`:

> --mirror
>
> Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies `--bare`. Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only maps local branches of the source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a `git remote update` in the target repository.

Per the above and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6150188/1426891), further updates can be made simply by running `git remote update` on the target (backup) repository.

Though you can also do a simple directory backup using `scp` or `rsync`, cloning the repository allows git to determine which objects need to be sent over, whereas filesystem tools (or other git-naive options) may need to re-hash and compare more state.