# Is there a way to update my cloned code from GitHub?

Tags: git, macos, github

So basically I'm using software from GitHub that I cloned a few days ago. Didn't do anything else. Just cloned it. So I was wondering how I could update the clone since a new version of the code has been released. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a git clone --mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150188/how-to-update-a-git-clone-mirror)

Comment: Not really! Thank you though.

Comment: Why does that link not answer your question?

Comment: Because its not really as in depth as I need it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is what you're looking for. It fetches changes from the repository on GitHub, called the remote, and merges them in to your local branch.

Comment: Thanks! How would I do this though? Its giving me an error saying that its not a git repo.

Comment: @TheMartian32 Are you definitely running this inside the cloned folder? You need to be there so you're inside the repository.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @The When you cloned the repo Git created a folder to put the contents in. You need to `cd` into that folder where the contents of the repository is to be able to run Git commands on that repository.

Comment: Thank you so much!