# git push error "error: src refspec xxx does not match any." using git flow

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I used to create an repo on my private git server

```
git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/poc/git_repo/local_display_multi_langs            .git/
```

Then I tried to `add remote` in my working copy on my mac.

```
git remote add origin ssh://poc@172.19.16.101/home/poc/git_repo/local_display_multi_langs.git
```

Executed the following commands

```
  514  git flow init
  519  git flow feature start read_xml
  524  git ci -am "first ci"
```

Then tried to push all branches to my private git server's repo
and got the exceptions as following

```
[src] $ git push origin feature
poc@172.19.16.101's password:
error: src refspec feature does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://poc@172.19.16.101/home/poc/git_repo/local_display_multi_langs.git'
```

Did I miss or misuse some steps ?

How to push all the branches on my working copy to remote server ?

Then When I clone the project from my git server.

How to get the new cloned project and original project are identical.

### Thanks

Thanks for @VonC

Now I can push all the branches on my local working copy to remote server by

`git push origin --all`

But When I do git clone `ssh://poc@172.19.16.101/home/poc/git_repo/local_display_multi_langs.git`
under another folder.

```
[local_display_multi_langs] $ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature/read_xml
  remotes/origin/master
```

I saw the above branches which are strange to me.

Because I expect get the same results as the original working copy like the following.

Is there any way to get `clone from my remote server and restore the status as the original working copy`

```
[local_display_multi_langs] $ git br
  develop
* feature/read_xml
  master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I push all the branched on my working copy to remote server ?

You can do at least a:

```
git push origin --all
```

'`feature`' is a command of git-flow, not the name of a branch.
See [gitflow cheatsheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/).

'`feature`' translate into a branch *namespace*, defining a **[branch hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309)**.
Pushing only those feature branches would be:

```
git push origin refs/heads/feature/*:refs/remotes/origin/feature/*
```

Or you can [register the refspec in a .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915046/6309).

Comment: I thought `feature` is an default branch in `git flow`. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @poc no, `feature` is a branch *namespace*. You could push only `feature` branche*s* with a refspec (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) `git push origin refs/heads/feature/*:refs/remotes/origin/feature/*` (or specify that refspec in your `.gitconfig`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915046/6309)

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about the namespace in Git. I'll pick up the related knowledges. Thanks~ By the way, How could I get the 'same' working copy by git clone from my server

Comment: @poc a git clone will clone *all* remote branches: http://stackoverflow.com/a/72156/6309. (Unless you clone a clone: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5563349/6309). If you want those branches visible as your own local branches after a clone, you need to create them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309