# Linking gitolite configurations to git projects

Tags: git, gitolite

OK, so I have gitolite installed on a server. It automatically sets up test repos in ~/repositories. That is nice, but I want to manage repos at other places. My files are in `/home/website1/www`, `/home/websites2/www/`, etc. So I could theoretically go to `/home/website1/www/` and run `git init`, but if I do so is there any way I can integrate them in gitolite? I do not grasp how to 'link' the two...

NOTE: this is a first install of both git and gitolite, so I do have files on the server but do not yet have any version control system setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitolite only [supports bare repositories](http://groups.google.com/group/gitolite/browse_thread/thread/67895c08741ea536?pli=1) on the server.  I'm assuming you want to do this because you want to push to a website and have your site be updated?

If so, you could use a `post-receive` [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to copy your site to the directory you want.  If this is not the case, let me know and I will delete this answer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3838727/275354) looks like what you might want.