# how can I create a remote git repository that accepts pushes into the working tree?

Tags: git, repository, push, staging

Im trying to have a shared remote repository where team members can push their changes and see them live in a staging environment.

Ive looked some options but I'm still stuck. Bare repositories have no working tree, and ive tried a normal repository with receive.denyCurrentBranch set to false, (which lets me push to the remote) but the working tree still doesnt get updated until you log into the server and do a git reset.

Ideally id like to be able to just push to the repository (one command) and see the changes updated live.

Comment: this is not a good workflow for website deployment. Profer a bare repo with hooks. See http://ryanflorence.com/simple-git-deployment/

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3838727/720999). The OP seemingly did not know about the necessity to use hooks in the remote repository so I'm hesitating to marking this question for closing as duplicate.

Comment: I didnt mention in the question because I didnt think it was relevant but I do have a bare repo (origin) in addition to the others. Thanks to everyone who pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set up a `post-receive` hook on the remote repository to pull the changes to the working tree. With a bare repository, you can `git-archive` the HEAD and extract the archive to a directory, instead of updating a working tree.

Reference: [Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks); [git-archive](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)