# Push to remote server and Github

Tags: git

Summary: I want to edit files locally, then push to both Github and my web server.

I have the two remotes set up without issue, so right now I am sort of able to do this; however, I have to have branch A checked out locally, and branch B on the server. Then I have to SSH into the server and check out branch A (the one I want). I really don't even want or need a second branch, but many posts suggest that you can't or shouldn't push to a non-bare repository. There must be a better way. Even just using rsync would be easier than this (and I did it for a while).

Strangely, this never happens on Github. Almost all my repos only have one branch and I've never gotten this warning.

The warning message says that you can set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to ignore, but I don't know how safe/sane it is. I'm hoping someone will understand my vague description (which is due to my limited knowledge of git) and know the optimum solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to set-up a post-receive hook on a bare repo on your web server.
That way, this hook can:

- change directory and pull the new changes to the actual non-bare repo
- checkout the branch you want

See "[Git Post-Receive Hook for Website Staging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging)" and the work in "[Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)":

```
$ mkdir /var/www/www.example.org
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

(Note: fun fact, you can [push to two different remote repos simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/6309))

Comment: It took me a minute to digest: `/var/www/www.example.org` is the actual site dir on the server, the `post-receive` file goes in the bare repo on the server (must be a different dir), and the URL to push to is the bare repo. I actually read that guide you mentioned before asking. I got confused when the site.git dir didn't have any of my files, but I think I understand how it works now. Thanks.