# How push directly to remote server just using push?

Tags: git, branch, push

I got a remote `git` repository, I cloned it to my local repository, made local changes and when I push I got the message that I cant push to the master branch:

> [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)

I read that if I change the branch it works, I do it and works, but I can't work like that; I need that when I push changes from local to remote repository the changes apply in the same time to the files on remote repository, I don't want to return to master branch, or merge branches.

I read too that I can use bare repositories, it doesn't work for me.

I see some videos where guys push directly to remote repository and just need to enter a passphrase, but I don't know how to do all that to work like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging. Even if it's not an exact duplicate, that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I read too that I can use bare repositories, it doesn't work for me.

It should work for you though, if you get that the process described in [Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) is using a **bare** repo (to which you push to), with a post-receive hook:

```
$ mkdir /var/www/www.example.org
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

The advantage, in your case, is that the hook can checkout any branch you need.

Note: the passphrase is likely related to using for a push address an ssh one, and using a private password-protected ssh key.