# Why do I need to force git to sync my remote repository?

Tags: git, push

I have a local repository that I've cloned from my remote repository (all on one machine). I wanted to make sure that my remote repository picked the changes from my local repository so I did a `git push origin`.

I changed my working directory to my remote repository; the change had propagated to the log file (i.e. doing `git log` showed the change) but my actual working directory didn't show the change. I did a `git checkout HEAD` but the CWD still didn't change. It wasn't until I did a `git checkout --force HEAD` that the CWD synced up.

I suspect this is happening because the remote repository isn't a bare repository. So two questions:

1. Is there a way that I can make the remote repository automatically sync (i.e. discard local changes) on a `git push`?
2. Why do I need to to use `--force` to get it to sync up? What *should* be the process of syncing it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your push (to a non-bare) repo succeeded, it is because:

- either you pushed a branch which wasn't checked out on your remote repo (the non-bare remote repo)
- or `receive.denyCurrentBranch` was set to `false` or `ignore` in the [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

In the latter case, any current local modification wouldn't be erased by that push.
Only a `git checkout --force` would reset the working directory to the actual index content referenced by `HEAD`.

The usual way to ensure synchronization between two non-bare repo is by adding an intermediate bare repo (to which you push) with a post-receive hook which will go the actual remote repo (the non-bare one) and *pull* from the updated bare repo.
The usual example: [Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto), which I use in:

- "[Push to remote server and Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891409/push-to-remote-server-and-github/10892791#10892791)"
- "[How to reset staged changes on the remote after a push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086405/how-to-reset-staged-changes-on-the-remote-after-a-push/10087795#10087795)"
- "[How push directly to remote server just using push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905739/how-push-directly-to-remote-server-just-using-push/10905899#10905899)"

When you are pulling, make sure to unset `GIT_DIR`: see "[Calling '`git pull`' from a git `post-update` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542854/calling-git-pull-from-a-git-post-update-hook/3542926#3542926)"