# git post-receive hook does not delete files

Tags: git

I'm trying out git at the moment, and am trying to create a workflow so that a push to a bare remote repo on the server will update 2 different sites based on different branches.

The post-receive hook is:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/development/ git checkout -f master
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/production/ git checkout -f production
```

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838804/1097483 but with a few modifications.

Unfortunately while testing it, commiting a new test file to any of the branches will be pushed and successfully update the web root, but for deleting the same test file, the web root still retains a copy of the deleted file.

Does anyone know how I can get the post-receive hook to force a delete?

Comment: The basic problem here is that you're deploying to *two different* work-trees, from *one* repository. The one repository has one *index*, which keeps track of what's in the one, single, work-tree. This means the one index carefully records what is in `/www/development`, and then uses that to touch the same directory, `/www/production`, as lightly as possible. Now that Git knows what's in `production` it makes sure to not touch that same `development` much next time, and so on. See the problem? We have *two work-trees*, so we need *two index* files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/development/ git checkout -f master
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/development/ git clean -fdx
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/production/ git checkout -f production
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/production/ git clean -fdx
```

based off @Koraktor 's answer.

Comment: This is likely to work in most cases, but is not the right approach: it could still fail to check something out in some cases. You should either remove the target work-tree entirely (Git then notices that its index is out of date and rebuilds everything), or use two different index files a la `git worktree add` (`git worktree` is new in Git 2.5 and later and may not be quite what you want here anyway; you can just set up a `GIT_INDEX_FILE`) per deployment target.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [`git-reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) and [`git-clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean):

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/development/ git reset --hard master
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/development/ git clean -fdx
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/production/ git reset --hard production
GIT_WORK_TREE=/www/production/ git clean -fdx
```

Comment: It didn't exactly work, not exactly sure if its due to permissions or something: (using TortoiseGit)

`remote: error: packfile ./objects/pack/pack-<random string here>.pack cannot be accessed
remote: HEAD is now at <another random string> test`

but I managed to get it working with a bit of modification.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the work-tree checkout does not record any information about the repository in the working directory. So when updating an already checked-out version, Git will not be able to tell which diff it would have to apply and as such which files it needs to remove.

Easiest solution would be to remove all files in the folders before checking them out..

Comment: Thanks for explaining what happens behind the scenes, that makes sense.