# Is it possible to use git-clean in post-receive hook for bare repo?

Tags: wordpress, git

I have a bare git repository set up on a wordpress hosting service and have followed some instructions to set up a post-receive hook ([pagely git setup](https://support.pagely.com/hc/en-us/articles/203031474-Setting-up-git-on-Pagely-VPS-Enterprise-for-1-click-deployment))  As I understand it the work-tree is placed in a different directory referred to as the DEPLOYDIR.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is when a push request is received it will perform a git -clean on a few directories. If anyone is familiar with wordpress, our git has

- file1
- file2
- wp-content

  - mu-plugins
  - plugins
  - themes

I would like to be able to clean mu-plugins, plugins, and themes and remove any thing that was added manually except for what is in our .gitignore.

I tried this variation of the post-receive linked above:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
## store the arguments given to the script
read oldrev newrev refname

## Where to store the log information about the updates
LOGFILE=./post-receive.log
# The deployed directory (the running site)
DEPLOYDIR=/data/s12345/q1234/r4564

## Record the fact that the push has been received 
echo -e "Received Push Request at $( date +%F )" >> $LOGFILE
echo " - Old SHA: $oldrev New SHA: $newrev Branch Name: $refname" >> $LOGFILE

## Update the deployed copy
echo "Starting Deploy" >> $LOGFILE

echo " - Starting code update"
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git checkout wpqa -f
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR/wp-content/plugins" git clean -fd
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR/wp-content/themes" git clean -fd
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR/wp-content/mu-plugins" git clean -fd
echo " - Finished code update"
echo "Finished Deploy" >> $LOGFILE
```

After I made a push, everything was removed!

Pushing to ssh://username@helloworld.vendor.com:/data/git/mydirectory.git

remote:  - Starting code update
remote: Switched to branch 'qa'
remote: Removing stuff_that_is_in_the_repo/
remote: Removing stuff_in_your_gitignore/
...etc.

Any suggestions for how to refer to the specific paths of the work tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [the `git clean` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html), you can simply add the set of `<path>`s to the end of the command (prefixed with `--` if any of the paths resemble options; in your case they do not so you will be OK without the `--` but it's a good habit to get into).  Hence:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git checkout wpqa -f
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git clean -fd -- \
    wp-content/plugins wp-content/themes wp-content/mu-plugins
```

(I broke up the last line for display purposes; you can do the same, or just do it as one big line without the backslash.)

Note that `git clean` normally has no function on a *bare* repository, since a bare repository has no work-tree and `git clean` removes files from the work-tree.  When you use the `git --work-tree=... command [ options ]` code path or the `$GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable, however, you are supplying a work-tree, which overrides the "bare-ness".  The problem with the method you tried is that you are supplying three different work-trees, none of which is the same as the work-tree you supplied for the `checkout` step.

Comment: Thank you. This is working for me. I was originally trying to follow suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560625/git-post-receive-hook-does-not-delete-files) but I didn't understand how the GIT_WORK_TREE variable worked.