# Git Hooks - Automated Server Deployment Sync Files

Tags: javascript, bash, git, server, continuous-integration

I have the below bash script that is on a server where a I have setup a self hosted bare git repo. It has a post-receive git hook to auto deploy code from a git push to the dev branch or production branch. I am having issues modifying this so it will update **and** delete files as I push them to the bare self hosted git repo. I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) tutorial for the basic setup.

Can anyone help??

```
#!/bin/sh
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [[ $ref = refs/heads/master ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=/home/mywebsite/public_html --git- 
 dir=/home/mywebsite/gitrepo/mywebsite.git checkout -f master
    else
        if [[ $ref = refs/heads/dev ]];
        then
            echo "Development ref received. Deploying dev branch to staging..."
            git --work-tree=/home/mywebsite/dev_public_html --git-dir=/home/mywebsite/gitrepo/mywebsite.git checkout -f dev
        else
            echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Looks good. `git checkout -f` shoud update and remove files. Well, it shoud remove files that had been committed and checked out but later were removed and pushed. What's your problem?

Comment: When I do a git push with a file I deleted on my local machine it never gets updated on the working tree on the server. I have to manually go and delete the files/directories. git checkout -f is updating the files, but it just doesn't delete them for some reason.

Comment: Your hook doesn't work for me at all because of error `remote: hooks/post-receive: 6: hooks/post-receive: [[: not found`. I'll test it with bash…

Comment: Yep, you are right — checkout updates but doesn't delete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14560772/7976758 The problem with `git clean` approach is obvious — you're at risk of deleting too much (files that you need but that are not tracked at all).

Comment: My advise is to run `git diff --diff-filter=D --name-status oldrev..newrev` in the bare repo and remove listed files from the worktree(s).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076744/7976758