# Git post-receive hook for website publishing - selected files not working

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838804/427083) I tried to implement the following:

When pushing to the web repo, I do not want the whole repository contents to be copied to my web directory, but only certain files/directories.

So, in my `post-receive` hook I do this:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/full/path/to/web/directory git checkout -f -- web/index.php
```

However, very strangely the version of `index.php` in the directory never updates correctly. While a `git log` inside my bare repository directory showed the latest commits that were pushed to it the version of `index.php` is a previous one.

Also, I created a file called `test` and added that to the paths above to be copied into the work tree - this also did not show up.

The file is definitely executed. I added an `echo` command that shows up on my console, and I do some cleanup in the directory that is working as expected. All the files are there and updated. (I checked with a brand new `git clone`.) There is only one branch, `master`.

All this is very frustrating because it worked well when I first set it up. Don't know what could be wrong here. Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

I tried the following:

```
# added "testfile" at the end of the checkout line in post-receive

echo "Test" > testfile
git add testfile 
git commit -m "Test."
git push web

>...
> remote: error: pathspec 'testfile' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>...

cd ..
git clone <remote web> newdir

>...

cd newdir
cat testfile

> Test
```

So the repo gets updated as expected but the new file is not recognized found. Maybe something wrong with the path specification?

Comment: One obvious thing to ask... that `git checkout` will use whatever branch is current in the `--bare` repo (per its HEAD).  Is that the same as the branch being pushed-to?

Comment: Good question. There is only one branch, "master".

Comment: I updated my question with another test.

Comment: News: I added the branch name "master" after `checkout -f` and it worked. Why could that be?

Comment: I don't know off-hand why specifying the branch name would make a difference.