# Make my git repo customer facing site

Tags: git

So I want to have a git repo on my server which holds my website, one I can push to and users can see from the domain name.

I ssh'd into my server and did:

```
git --bare init
```

This was located in the file structure `/public_html/project`. Then on my local repo I did:

```
git init
```

added the remote and did an initial commit and pushed up to the server.

When I navigate to the server (`staging.com/public_html/project`) I just see the git files, where are my actual website files which the server can render?

Or is this a poor understanding of GIT?

Comment: IMO you are using the wrong tool. Git is used to keep a history of changes of your source code, not to deploy web pages.

Comment: What would be a better way to deploy and version control a site with many people?

Comment: @KurzedMetal Tell that to Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Bare repositories have no working directory. There are no checked out copies of any files for you to work with, or for your web server to serve. That's the whole point of the `--bare` option you used. If you want there to be usable files on the remote, don't use `--bare`.

Comment: Even if it wasn't `--bare`, he would have to `git pull` on the server after each push.

Comment: I used bare as i was getting an error when using a working remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
 remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
 remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
 remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
 remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.

Comment: @user2389087, this support's KurzedMetal's comment on your question. Git isn't meant as a deployment tool, and using it as one can be tricky. You can't simply `git push` into a directory on a remote machine, at least not out of the box. You'll need to `git pull` from the server, or set up a post receive hook to automate your site deployment, or something else like that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above

Using Git to deploy isn't the best solution

In the end I set up git as a working tree
Set up a post receive hook to update the head each time

If anyone else wants to follow this path, these links helped

[Git Post-Receive Hook for Website Staging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging)

[Using git to deploy a website](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)