# git intermediary repository ( as a proxy to another)

Tags: git, gitorious

Is is possible to have a git repository ( clonable and pushable) be itself a clone of another remote repo?

The scenario:

We have an installation of gitorious for our company's git hosting. We want to keep it updated but add some very private features ( mostly deploy scripts), hence the need to a pushable project. The desired workflow would be:

- create a mygitorous as a pushable git repo
- clone gitorious-official into mygitorious (not as submodule, as ref)
- users now can clone and push mygitorious
- I can then merge mygitorious with gitorious-official to update from upstream
- I can update my deployed clone
- users can update their clones with merged version

PS. Since these deploy scripts are very sensitive, I cannot simply make a public clone in gitorious and use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  The whole idea behind a distributed version control system like `git` is that no repository is "special".  Any repository can be a clone of or destination of zero, one, or more other repositories.

For example, assuming I have a repository `repo1.git`, I can do this:

```
$ git clone --bare repo1.git repo2.git
$ git clone repo2.git repo3
$ cd repo3
$ ...make some changes and commit...
$ git push
$ cd ../repo2.git
$ git push
```

If you follow that along, you can see I pushed repo3 --> repo2, and then repo2 --> repo1.

Responding to your comment:

You can't run `git checkout` in a bare repository.  That's what `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` means.  When you `git clone` a repository, you get two things:

- A copy of the repository, contained in a `.git` directory, and
- A "working copy", or "work tree", which is a directory containing the checked-out copies of files in the repository.  A number of commands (`checkout`, `pull`) only make sense when you're interacting with the working copy.

Note, however, that it is tricky to push *into* a non-bare repository (that is, a repository with an associated working tree); git will throw an error without explicit configuration.  You would see something along the lines of:

```
To /home/lars/tmp/so/repo
 ! [remote rejected] foo -> foo (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/lars/tmp/so/repo'
```

This is because it would be surprising to have changes happening inside the repository underneath your working tree if other people were pushing into it.  You can read more 
in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804545/what-is-this-git-warning-message-when-pushing-changes-to-a-remote-repository).

Comment: While this is true for multiple local repos, the `cd` step isn't appropriate if they are on distinct servers. But the general point is still true - it's a `web of trust`.

Comment: Of *course* it's not appropriate if they are on distinct servers.  This was an *example* meant to demonstrate a particular *point* and I wanted it to be *reproducible* at a simple command line without needing to set up remote repositories.

Comment: @larks Thanks. For my special case, repo2 as already created as empty remote repo by gitorious. I tried `git add remote ...` and `fetch` (ok) but checkout failed. I am not sure I could erase and clone. Any hint?

Comment: `remote add` and `fetch` succeeded but `checkout` failed?  Can you post the commands you're using and the exact output you're seeing?

Comment: @larska, apologies for any misunderstandings.