# How can i work with SVN if not every one in group are

Tags: svn, version-control, web

I have tried setting up a logical way of using subversion (or any other VCS really but i've played more with svn).

Let me start with explaining my problem, We are a few coworkers which needs to be changing our customers websites on a daily basis, however the customers also can change some files via their "admin panel" on the website. As well as some files are generated on the servers, logfile, export/import data, sitemaps etc.

We are now working over FTP, and to maintain some kind of file history we make .bak.revision#.php files but it is *almost* unmanagable. On top of that i am using Netbeans as my IDE, which requires local copies of the files.

To start a project i need to sync changed files with my customer (or worst case download full project) (which can take forever).

I really enjoy working with Netbeans, but now i sometimes end up using notepad++ instead.

I set up a pretty nice way of working with SVN with a post-commit hook that exports the project into a http folder that way i can do an update on my local copy, make changes and then commit -done-

But i don't want to overwrite files that might have been changed on the server, for example the customers CSS-file which they can make changes to themselves.

So i thought i cannot be the only one to have this problem, how to work with SVN if not everybody in the team does? (in my case the customers)

i may be able to use svn:ignore on those files i guess?

(this is test environment) My post commit hook is very simple;
svn export file:///svn/repo/LIVE /var/www/html/ --force

---

EDIT
Plausible solution i will look into, if i create a pre-commit, or even better ?pre-update? hook to import overwrite files already in the repo, that would solve my problem, would it not?

NVM
The Import runs commit.
commit and pre commit would not work well, since it would create an endless loop

---

Kindest Regards 
Iesus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:::My findings:::

(@LazyBadger This answer was to long to put in a comment.)

Export does not work, i need a real working directory.
But i can deny access directly in the httpd.conf, in other words no hassle with the .htaccess files.

I can use UPDATE to keep the web directory up to date in a post-commit script. (example below)

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1" REV="$2" cd /var/www/html/ 
MESSAGE=$(svnlook propget --revprop -r $REV $REPOS svn:log) 
Author=$(svnlook propget --revprop -r $REV $REPOS svn:author) 
CHANGES=$(svnlook changed -r $REV $REPOS)

echo "" >> /$REPOS/SVN.Log 
echo "Commit | $REPOS | $REV | $MESSAGE | $CHANGES | $Author" >> /$REPOS/SVN.Log 
echo update >> /$REPOS/SVN.Log 
svn update >> /$REPOS/SVN.Log 
echo klar >> /$REPOS/SVN.Log
```

To keep the customer-edited files in sync i can either use ignore (to simply not have those files in repository), will most probably be used for binary files and log files to keep the size of the repo under control.

Then  we can use a commit daemon to keep the repository up to date, unfortunately the EasySVN solution (great software by the way, free as well, also it can be used with any server) was not for Linux environment (just yet).

*By the way the EasySVN could with ease be used for backing up files to any SVN with the great advantage of file history. Heads up! in order to use svn+ssh support you will need to download a sshclient which can handle -q flag (for example from this package: http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=3794). And use pageant from putty*

But i could create a commit script or run the commits by using CRON once in a while, it really should be embedded into the php save function but that's a major job, perhaps in future releases of our software it will :)

Example commit script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html/ && svn commit -m webedit -q
```

That one can of course be improved alot, for example we coule be checking for changes first ^^.

Example Daemon like script to check for changes and commit if needed

```
#!/bin/bash
SVNREPOS=( "/var/www/html/" )
cd /PATH/TO/THIS/SCRIPT/
LCK_FILE=`basename $0`.lck
if [ -f "${LCK_FILE}" ]; then
  echo LOCK exists
  MYPID=`head -n 1 $LCK_FILE`  

  if [ -n "`ps -p ${MYPID} | grep ${MYPID}`" ]; then
    echo `basename $0` is already running [$MYPID].
    exit
  else
    rm "${LCK_FILE}" -f
    sh $0
    exit
  fi

else
  echo $$ > $LCK_FILE
   while :; do
    for i in "${SVNREPOS[@]}"
     do
      cd $i
         #What are we doing here? Basicly we are testing if anything is to commit, if so commit it
         test ! $(svn st|wc -l) -eq 0 && svn ci -m SERVERCOMMIT -q 
      sleep 5s
     done
    done
echo ENDED LOOP IT SHOULD NOT HAVE DONE THAT
 rm "${LCK_FILE}" -f
 sh $0
fi

echo $$ > $LCK_FILE
```

Init.d script to start/stop daemon

```
#! /bin/bash
#SVN CHANGED MONITOR DAEMON
. /etc/init.d/functions

RETVAL=0
SCRIPTDAEMON=/PATHTO/changemonitor.sh
getpid() {
    pid=`ps -eo pid,command | grep "sh $SCRIPTDAEMON" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{ print $1 }'`
    }

start(){
    gprintf "Starting SVNChangeMonitor: "
    echo_failure
    getpid
    if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
      sh $SCRIPTDAEMON &
    fi

     getpid
     if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
         echo_success
     else
         echo_failure
     fi
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
    gprintf "Stopping SVNChangeMonitor: "
    echo_failure
    getpid
    if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
        kill -s kill $pid
        rm $SCRIPTDAEMON.lck -f

        getpid
         if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
             echo_success
         else
             echo_failure
         fi

    else
        echo_failure
    fi
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart)
        stop
        start
                gprintf "SVNChangeMonitor is restarted\n"
        ;;
  status)
        getpid
        if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
               gprintf "SVNChangeMonitor (pid %s) is running." "$pid"
               echo_success
                echo
        else
                RETVAL=1
                gprintf "SVNChangeMonitor is stopped\n"
                                echo
        fi
        ;;
  *)
        gprintf "Usage: %s {start|stop|restart|status}\n" "$0"
        echo
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Thanks for your kind help and pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Most logical and technical way in your case (but **not easiest**) will be

- converting site tree into Working Copy of common (with your Netbeans) repository - which require install Subversion on server and some post-install tricks, thus: SSH root-access to host
- commit direct changes on site into repo with crontab job|special button in admin panel
- changing post-commit hook, which, in this case, have to update server's WC after commit from "foreign" host

More exotic way: Subversion for everybody (for some users - behind the scene)

- Everybody use Subversion (directly) or indirectly - nobody touch files on site
- Changes from repository stored (as export) on site, as it happens now

For developers this way change nothing. For technically mediocre customers **you** suggest, prepare and configure [EasySVN](http://svn-ref.assembla.com/easysvn.html) (and, therefore, Assembla's repository) - they'll just get local folder (or tree), all changes in which are (*automagically*) synced with related repository (reverse direction also work - background updates from repo delivered to WC). SSH or FTP tools of Assembla space transfer changes to site (automatically on commit or on demand by hand)

Comment: Am i understanding you if you mean that the admin-interface should trigger a commit? And to be able to do so, have the public site as checkout instead of export? In that case i don't really like the idéa of having .svn-folders public.

Comment: @IesusSonesson - if you don't like - don't have! .htaccess rules in ignored file preventing access to .svn dir easy

Comment: Sorry if i have offended you in any way; i guess i simply was looking for another solution that would not clutter the web server with .svn directories nor have to supply the SVN authentication information to a php application (there should be at least 800 .htaccess-files to edit and about 1200 php files to add commit code to)

Comment: @IesusSonesson - no offending at all, I just can't see problem: for 1.7 WC you have: 1. single .svn dir in Working Copy 2. single rule in single .htacess file 3. svn-credentials **not used** in php-app - you call svn cli from php and store credentials for repo in usual svn-way. And **you have not another way**, if you can't prohibit direct editing of site

Comment: It seems more tempting now, i did not know about 1,7 (only one .svn) will defenetly look in to that!

Comment: Just saw you had updated the post,  the EasySVN solution does not look bad at all i'll look into that one as well!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DVCS locally on the webserver. Compared to centralized a VCS, the decentralized one decouples what happens on the customer side from what happens within your team. Also, this scenario is all about merging and any DVCS worth its salt is all about merging, and does it best.

I give here a concrete workflow with Git, but that is doable with any other DVCS. I will assume there is a repository `{TEAM}` that is reachable both from the team and from the webserver to make the workflow here simpler, but there are multiple ways to do otherwise. You just can't push for your development team directly to the webserver's repository in a way that changes the files, see my explanation on [why you can't push to a checked out branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117823/git-push-error-refusing-to-update-checked-out-branch/14878413#14878413).

## The webserver keeps history

In , you have one main branch, **TEAM/dev** where your development occurs. You create your webserver's repository like this:

```
~$ git clone -b dev {TEAM} /var/www/mystuff
~$ cd /var/www/mystuff
mystuff$ git checkout -b locall-changes
```

At some points, you will commit whatever the webserver has done. It could be a cron job, some PHP code or a manual intervention:

```
mystuff$ git ci --all -m "Webserver modifications"
```

The **--all** option tells Git to commit every modification to files already tracked by Git. If the webserver may create new files that you want to track, you'll have to put ignore patterns (for log files and such) and commit this way:

```
mystuff$ git add .
mystuff$ git ci -m "Webserver modifications"
```

Note at this point, no communication has occurred between the webserver and your team since the initial cloning. That's the strength of a DVCS: the operation of the webserver and its keeping history is totally autonomous. You can go bankrupt or be wiped clean by a nuke, not only will it continue to work, but someone can fill in and continue what you were doing seamlessly.

## You merge with your development

You can track the webserver by having its repository be a remote on your side (you do that once only):

```
myrepo$ git remote add webserver ssh://webserver/var/www/mystuff
myrepo$ git fetch webserver
myrepo$ git branch changes webserver/local-changes
```

When you want to publish your new code to the webserver, you first get its history and check how it merges:

```
myrepo$ git co changes
myrepo$ git pull
```

This will fetch new commits from the remote webserver and update the **changes** branch to what **local-changes** is now on the webserver.

```
myrepo$ git merge dev
```

Now you check how the merge went and when you have resolved conflicts and committed the merge, you make it available in {TEAM}:

```
myrepo$ git push {TEAM} changes
```

## Back on the webserver

One the webserver, you now just have to pull that merge. Only problem is, some new commits may have been made in the meantime. To be sure, you can force updating the branch only when your merge is a direct descendant of the current commit (Git calls this a **fast-forward** merge):

```
mystuff$ git pull --ff-only {TEAM}/changes
```

If no FF is possible, this command doesn't change the files and exits with a non-zero error code, which makes it possible to let a automated script trigger it and let you know if it didn't really happen.

Comment: To use a VCS on the server and put a commit into the admin code was the first suggestion ^^, thanks anyway!

Comment: What do you mean? You considered this solution and decided to try otherwise?

Comment: What i meant was that the solution was already suggested before you in this thread.

but no, not quite what i was looking for as I'm not very keen on making changes to all of those admin-files.

A nice scenario would be to commit changes made before me when i run "upate". that way i would get the latest changes made before me. unfortunately i cannot find any way to do pre-update hooks

Comment: Another way i've been looking into is to see difference on who is running command, and that way do stuff before the command runs;

For example if i were to run a commit in the pre-commit to be sure not to loose changes made before me, every time commit is run with a keyword in the message commit is run before commit is done or something similar

Comment: No, I'm quite sure noone suggested using a DVCS, and in your scenario, there is a huge difference between using a DVCS like Git or Hg and using SVN. Sorry, I realize now my answer was actually too short to make my point. I'll try and expand it soon.

Comment: I'm sorry if i was being rude or short in my response, Please do, i did not realize the difference in this case. I am open to using any VCS and looked into both Subversion and mercurial. (and like them both)

Comment: What it looks like right now i am prepared to ignore the files the customer can change themselves, it is a limited group of files anyway. 

Some of which we perhaps do not want versionized anyway (for example log files?). 

I am trying to understand what are the usual ways, and how people are using VCS as i said in the initial post some one must have been in the same situation

Comment: Thank you for your update, it makes sense of course, i will def. set up a test with git/mercurial as well :)

Comment: The essence is the same as my solution with subversion >below>

Perhaps the DVCS is better or more reliable, my /etc/init.d (service) daemon would work great with this as well i'll just have to change the commands for the commiting code.

I will set up a testing enviroment to try git or mercurial to see whatever i like the best. I thanks for taking the time to write your your good tutorial (+1)

Comment: I think it's an illusion that the essence be the same. On the VCS front only, it could seem that a DVCS doesn't change much, because it's still just committing stuff and merging branches. But if you use a centralized VCS, you have a very serious reliability issue: if the connection between the VCS client and its server fails, you lose the ability to commit and when the next commit comes, you have lost history. It also means that only the team in control of (or at least having some kind of acccess to) the VCS server can do the maintenance properly. So a DVCS actually makes a huge difference.

Comment: I did not mean the difference between the two techniques but how to address the issue with auto commits ^^

Comment: Yes, of course, as far as triggering the commit goes, they are identical. `svn add && svn ci` in one case, `git add && git commit` in the other…

Comment: Still not what i ment :P. More like the way to commit by using cron / daemon / put commit in save-code, which i have understood is necessary, i hoped it was not, but i guess when i think about it it was just stupid of me ^^

Comment: Just updating you on the current status; I have created a similar way of working with Mercurial (i choose it over Git because i had it installed and my friend recommends it highly, no offense at all I'm still going to look into Git ^^). The actual way of working seems a little bit less effective (in SVN i just press update and get up to date, in mercurial i need pull -> update instead and for some reason they've hidden the push event in both Eclipse and NetBeans and it's easily forgotten. Guess it's a matter of habit), but as i suspected the commits are blitzing fast. Thanks Again!

Comment: No offense, you're actually following advice I've given in the past about how to choose a DVCS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138621/best-version-control-for-lone-developer/161953#161953

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to force the customer to use svn (knowingly or not), just treat the customer site as a replica, and use a tool like [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to keep the unmanaged side (the customer) with the managed side (yours).   Unison is somewhat like rsync except that it handles changes in both directions, so files that the customer changes will get copied down to your system.

So your workflow is:

- unison  (sync the local with the remote; pull their changes down)
- svn commit (check in their changes)
- edit edit edit
- svn commit (check in your changes)
- unison  (sync the remote with local, also pull down anything they might have changes)