# How to pull to code change to submodule using git?

Tags: git

I have two repositories on a local machine.

```
   main-repo
   sub-repo
```

I added the sub-repo as a submodule in main-repo.  The sub-repo contains a readme file.

Originally, I kept the directory name the same as the repo name.
I changed the sub-repo directory to sub1.  Hopefully, that clears up
any confusion.

```
   main-repo
        sub1
             readme
```

If I made changes to readfile from the main-repo/sub-repo/readme, NOT from sub-repo/readme directly.

These are the steps I have done.  Since this is only on my local machine, I added the submodule using this command

```
 cd main-repo
 git submodule add file:///c:/Users/Worker/Git/t5-sub/sub-repo sub1
```

1. cd main-repo/sub1
2. git checkout master
3. edit readme file
4. git commit .
5. git push
6. cd sub-repo directory
7. git status

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   readme
```

When I look at the content of readme file, it does not have the changes.
How do pull the changes from main-repo to the sub-repo ?

Comment: "*I went over to the sub-repo directory…*" There is a problem in your description — there're 2 directories named `sub-repo`. My advice is to [edit] the question and rename one of them. After that it will be much more clear to us what is where.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `git push` at point 5 because you push to a non-bare repository which is not recommended. Actually I expect an error on such a push with message ["remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11117823/7976758).

You should pull to it, not push:

```
cd sub-repo
git remote add sub ../main-repo/sub1
git pull sub master
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried @phd suggestion.  It did not work for me.
After playing around a bit, I found this to work for me.

```
cd sub-repo
git restore --staged readme
git checkout .
```