# Clone from a local repository, then pushing back the changes

Tags: git, repository, local, git-push, git-repo

I have a git repository on my local system in `/original/.git`. Now, I have cloned this repository in `/cloned_one/.git`. Everything looks fine. Here, I have the same files that I have in `/original` which is quite nice. I create a new file and commit it. Now, my cloned repo is one commit ahead. I want to push the changes but don't know how!

It becomes more tricky because I'm a bit confused about the following command's diversities and exact use-cases. I know some of them and actually worked with them somehow but I've seen a lot of users use them in the wrong place and that's what made me confused. Not sure when to use the following commands.

- `git fetch`
- `git rebase`
- `git push`
- `git merge`
- `git --force push`

Thanks.

Comment: *GIt* does not have "forks", just "clones". Certain hosting sites (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc) have "forks": these are server-side clones with extra added features. So a fork is site-specific, but generally means "extra added features". Are you using some hosting software (such as GitLab) that has these extra features, or are you just using Git, and hence you mean that you *cloned* the repository?

Comment: You are completely right. That was a mistake made by me. I meant I've cloned the repo. (edited the question)

the project is being hosted on Github. A lot of dirty codes in the project. It needs a huge change. I decided to recreate the entire project. A friend told me to clone it locally, make changes and then push back all commits. Thank you for checking out by the way.

Comment: OK. Just to be completely clear, now that you have mentioned GitHub: you mean that, locally, you did: `cd /; git clone original cloned_one`? (Not `cd /; git clone <github-url> cloned_one`, for instance.)

Comment: The original repo is cloned from a Github repository. I created another directory to clone the previously cloned repo (which is located on my system now) and start making changes and then, push it back. I actually cloned another one from the previously GitHub-cloned repo which means, the origin remote in the second cloned repo is not set to the Github host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git's remote repository can be from ssh, https, and directory.

In your example,

- `/original/.git` have remote origin that points to github (either via ssh or https, e.g.: `https://github.com/user/example.git`)
- `/cloned_one/.git` have remote origin that points to directory (e.g.: `/original/.git`

This looks like some kind of linked list:

```
[/cloned_one/.git] --origin--> [/original/.git] --origin--> [github]
```

Here is an example command to reproduce such setup:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone https://github.com/schacon/example.git original
Cloning into 'original'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 4
Receiving objects: 100% (4/4), 18.52 KiB | 3.70 MiB/s, done.
$ mkdir cloned_one
$ git clone /tmp/original cloned_one
Cloning into 'cloned_one'...
done.
$ cd cloned_one/
$ echo newfile > newfile.txt
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        newfile.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add newfile.txt 
$ git commit -m 'add new file'
[master e45e780] add new file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 newfile.txt
$ git remote -v
origin  /tmp/original (fetch)
origin  /tmp/original (push)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Now, the `cloned_one` is 1 commit ahead of `original`

You can push changes from `cloned_one` to `original` with (remember to `cd /tmp/cloned_one` first):

- `git push`
- `git push origin master`
- `git push /tmp/original master`

Here, the syntax of pushing is to specify where you want to push (e.g.: to origin, or to /tmp/original directory), and what branch you want to push

```
$ cd /tmp/cloned_one/
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 333 bytes | 333.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: 
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /tmp/original
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/tmp/original'
```

Now it says that you have trouble pushing to /tmp/original because its not a bare repo. You can fix this by either changing /tmp/original to bare repo, or just configure it to update its worktree when being pushed to like below:

```
$ cd /tmp/original/
$ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
$ cd /tmp/cloned_one/
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 333 bytes | 333.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To /tmp/original
   c3d5e92..e45e780  master -> master
```

Now, if you want to push your changes back to github (the origin of `/tmp/original`) you can push it from `/tmp/original` or from `/tmp/cloned_one`:

- `cd /tmp/original ; git push origin master`
- `cd /tmp/cloned_one ; git push https://github.com/username/example.git`

Notice that when pushing from `/tmp/original`, you can specify the target as `origin` (since the origin of /tmp/original is from github). While when pushing from `/tmp/cloned_one`, you have to specify the target as full URL.

You can also change `cloned_one`'s remote to point to github (search for git remote manual)

Further reading:

- what's a bare repo?

  - Bare repository is just a normal repository, but without the file checked out (e.g.: just the .git directory),
  - [What's the -practical- difference between a Bare and non-Bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository)
  - https://mijingo.com/blog/what-is-a-bare-git-repository
  - the content of a bare repository is the same with .git directory inside a non-bare repo (to convert a non-bare to bare, you just need to git config --bool core.bare true and delete its working directory)
- about why `! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)` issue happens, you can read:

  - [Git Push error: refusing to update checked out branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117823/git-push-error-refusing-to-update-checked-out-branch)
  - https://cbx33.github.io/gitt/chap6-5.html

Comment: Thank you so much for checking out. I did the exact steps you explained in your answer but missed the part you said that I need to make my origin repo as a bare repo. Now everything looks fine. Would you add some references for learning more about a Bare Repo and Worktree and why that issue (`! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)`) actually happens?

Comment: Bare repository is just a normal repository, but without the file checked out (e.g.: just the .git directory), you can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository or https://mijingo.com/blog/what-is-a-bare-git-repository

Comment: Do you mean an empty repo with only an initialized .git directory?

Comment: if you init it with --bare then yes, it's empty. But the content of a bare repository is the same with .git directory inside a non-bare repo (to convert a non-bare to bare, you just need to ```git config --bool core.bare true``` and delete its working directory)

Comment: about why `! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)` issue happens, you can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117823/git-push-error-refusing-to-update-checked-out-branch or https://cbx33.github.io/gitt/chap6-5.html

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Kristian. Are these topics and issues being explained in the Git advanced tutorials or something? Looking for a reference to understand Git a bit deeper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238910/discussion-between-alireza-and-kristian).

Answer (score 2):

## All about Git Commands

### TL;DR

To upload your changes to the repository you cloned, use `git push`. This applies even if you cloned a repository that was on your local machine.

### Local Branches & Remote Branches

To understand things, a repository normally has two sets of branches:

- Your local branches
- The remote branches

Normally when you list branches with `git branch`, it only lists the local branches. But you can list all of them with `git branch -a`:
[image]

Here, this shows my local branches, as well as the remote branches (colored in red, to indicate that they're remote)

When you run `git pull`, this actually does two steps:

- First, it runs `git fetch`. This will update all of the remote branches based on whatever's in the repo you cloned from. Note that this repo may not actually be on a remote server; it could be on your local machine, like in your case.
- Second, it runs `git merge` or `git rebase` depending on your config options. This will merge your remote branches into your local branches.

That's how your repository is updated.

### But would you ever fetch without merging?

Fetching without merging can be useful because it allows you to inspect remote changes *before* they're merged into your local branches. This can be done like so:

```
git fetch
git diff <your branch> origin/<your branch>
```

Running this in one of my repositories, I see the following changes have occured on the original repo I cloned from. (This uses [diff-so-fancy](https://www.google.com/search?channel=nus5&client=firefox-b-1-d&q=diff-so-fancy) to display the changes in a slightly prettier way, but it looks fine on normal git diff).

[image]

TL;DR: You don't usually need to fetch, but it's nice to view changes ahead of time

### Merging vs Rebasing

*Merging* is when you take two separate histories, and join them together with a merge commit.

Most commits have a parent, but merge commits have two parents (or three or more, in the case of octopus merges). Initial commits have zero parents, but they're special because nothing comes before them.

We can take a look at the commit graph of one of the projects I'm working on to see an example of this. Here, I did work in several feature branches, before creating pull requests for them to be merged back into the main branch.

[image]

I think graphs like this are pretty, but some people prefer linear histories, and that's where re-basing comes in.

Instead of joining two branches together, it just breaks one branch off, and glues it on top of the other one. [This is a good article that goes into detail about it.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)

#### What's pull with rebase?

If you have commits on your local branch (say, `main`), AND there are new commits on the remote branch (say, `origin/main`), then normally, as the final step in of the pull, git will merge the two, so that your local branch will now have all the commits from `origin/main`.

This is the one time I prefer rebasing to merging: it's nicer to just stick your local commits *on top of* the remote ones, so there aren't multiple branches in history.

I set rebasing as the default option using the following command:

```
git config --global pull.rebase merges
```

What this means is "rebase my local commits on top of the remote ones, but preserve any merges I did intentionally (like merging in a feature branch)". This is a good default to have, and it keeps me happy.

### git push, and git push --force

This is how you get your local changes, to the cloned repository.

`git push` will upload your changes, but if the remote repository has changes you don't have (say, because a coworker pushed to it before you), it'll refuse to upload your changes since that would cause a conflict. Fixing this is simple:

```
git pull
git push
```

- Pulling integrates your coworker's changes with yours by either merging or rebasing, so that yours can be uploaded
- Pushing then uploads your changes

#### So what about git push --force?

*Be very careful using this command.* It's main purpose is to re-write history, which is occasionally necessary if secrets got committed to a git repository, or if you need to permanently remove a file for other reasons.

If your coworker has changes on the remote repository, **force pushing will overwrite those changes**.

If you want to overwrite commits you made, a safer option is `--force-with-lease`, which will ensure that the only changes being overwritten are yours.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I like to think of this: **Repositories *share* commits, but they don't *share* branch names.**

A Git repository is, at its heart—the edges get all messy—really a pair of databases.  Both databases are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database):

- One of them—usually the biggest by far—is indexed / accessed by big ugly hash IDs.  These are commit hash IDs, and other internal Git object hash IDs.  So this is the objects database (although Git doesn't normally refer to it this way).
- The other one maps names—branch names, tag names, and all other kinds of names—to those big ugly hash IDs.  This lets us poor humans *use* Git; the hash IDs are not usable.  This is the names database, and each name maps to *exactly one* hash ID.  More than one name can map to one particular hash ID, and many hash IDs have no name that maps to them, so if you're used to thinking in terms of mathematical sets, this is a non-injective, non-surjective mapping (see [surjective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)).

Each *commit object* in the objects database has a *unique hash ID*.  The hash ID of *any* object, commit or not, is the result of running a cryptographic hash function over the data that make up the object (this is how Git does its consistency checking and its file-content-de-duplication).  But each commit is itself unique, thanks to several properties of a commit, so each one gets a unique hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  Using these commit hash IDs, then, any two *different* Git repositories, using compatible Git software—I call these "two Gits"—the two Gits can immediately tell whether they have the *same commits* or not, just by comparing commit hash IDs.<sup>2</sup>

What this all boils down to is that when we hook two Gits to each other, one—the sender—says things like *I have commit `a123456...`, would you like it?* to which the other replies either *yes please* or *no thanks, I have that one already*, and this allows the sender to send to the receiver just the commits the sender has that the receiver lacks.

This process—of sending commits I have that you don't, for instance—is a `git fetch` or `git push`, depending on who starts the conversation.  If you start the conversation to get commits from me, you are using `git fetch`.  If I start the conversation to send commits to you, I am using `git push`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Anyone familiar with the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) will immediately object that a hash function, even one with a 2<sup>160</sup> range (SHA-1) or 2<sup>256</sup> range (SHA-256), must eventually produce a collision.  This is true, and when that happens, Git stops functioning, so the hashes must be big enough that "eventually" is enough decades or centuries away not to worry.  (Due to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), this is harder than it might seem at first.)

<sup>2</sup>Due to the DAG that the commits form, we can do much better than just listing out all raw hash IDs, but if we had two fairly small repositories—say a few thousand commits each—it would be easy enough to just list all the hash IDs, to see who has which commits.

---

#### That's most of what there is to using more than one Git repository

Seriously, this kind of transfer is *all we need*, and is *all there was in primeval Git*, for connecting two Gits to each other.  By comparing hash IDs and sending commits I have that you don't, you wind up sharing my commits.  If I then turn around and get, from you, any commits *you* have that *I* don't, we're now equal in terms of the set of commits we have.  But this isn't a *convenient* way to *use* Git, so we now add a few extras.

#### Branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and so on

Humans are bad at hash IDs: `e9e5ba39a78c8f5057262d49e261b42a8660d5b9`.  Say what?  There are probably a few people who can repeat back to you a list of Git-repository-for-Git tag hash IDs, if they've read them, but I for one will transpose the characters sometimes, and don't bother trying to memorize them.  That's what the *computer* is for.  I let the computer remember the hash IDs for me: `master` might hold `e9e5ba39a78c8f5057262d49e261b42a8660d5b9` right now.  Later, `master` will hold some *other* hash ID.  Whatever hash ID it holds, that is, by definition, the *latest* commit on *my* `master` branch in this Git repository.

When we use `git fetch`, Git maintains all of this stuff for us in a nice way.  We create a *remote*—a short name like `origin`—under which we store a conventional URL such as `ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git`, or a pathname like `/absolute/path/to/dir/.git`, or whatever is appropriate.<sup>3</sup>

Now that we *have* this short name, `origin` or `fred` or whatever we choose, *our* Git can call up *their* Git—that is, our Git software can use ssh or https or whatever, to reach out to their Git software; our Git will operate in our repository, and their Git will operate in their repository—and once we've called up their Git, we can use `git fetch` to get commits from them.  We do this with a simple:

```
git fetch origin
```

for instance.

Their Git lists out their *branch* names and the corresponding commit hash IDs.  Our Git inspects these hash IDs and uses that to figure out if they have commits that we don't.  If we don't limit our Git,<sup>4</sup> our Git now brings over all of their commits that we don't already have, so now we share their commits.

But: our *branch* names are stuff *we* use to find specific commits in *our* repository, that *we like* for some specific reason.  Our `git fetch` *does not touch our branch names*.  Instead, our Git takes each of their *branch* names and changes these into *remote-tracking names*.<sup>5</sup>  Git does this by sticking the remote name—in this case, `origin`—in front of the branch name, plus a slash.  So this is where `origin/main` or `origin/master` comes from: that's *our copy* of *their branch name*.  It's our Git's way of remembering their Git's `main` or `master` (whichever one they have).

So, `git fetch` gets us their *commits*, but does nothing with our own branches.  Due to the hashing tricks that Git uses, *all* objects—including all commits—are completely read-only, so this update only *adds new commits* to our repository.  We share their commits but not their branch names.

---

<sup>3</sup>A very short relative path like `../d/.git` isn't much longer or harder to type than `origin`, so for this kind of case, you might be tempted to leave out the remote name.  But don't do it!  Git needs that remote name to form the remote-tracking names.  If you skip using a remote name, you're using the primeval mode, which Git still supports, it's just a pain in the <insert body part>.

<sup>4</sup>You can deliberately limit your `git fetch` to cut down on network traffic or whatever.  This is mostly unnecessary most of the time, since Git is clever about only bringing over any *needed* objects.  In some rare cases it can be useful, though.

<sup>5</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  They're not *branch* names though, not in our repository anyway.  They're *our copies* of *someone else's* branch names.  So from our point of view these are non-branch names that merely happen to "track" someone else's (branch) names.  Git over-uses both the verb *track* and the adjective *branch*, but we can cut down this overuse just a smidgen here.

---

#### From this point on, you work locally, at least until `git push`

What you have at this point is:

- all the commits;
- your own branch names; and
- your copy / memory of their branch names.

You work with *your* repository by extracting specific commits (`git checkout`) into your *working tree* and Git's *index* or *staging area* (two terms for the same thing).  You eventually make new commits, which add on to the existing commits.  When you do make a new commit, Git *automatically updates your current branch name*, so that your branch names automatically include your new commits.

You've asked about merge and rebase, and these are both actually quite large topics, but they're pretty well covered elsewhere.  Remember that `git merge` mostly means *combine work*.  Though `git merge` is full of exceptions to the usual ways of combining work, this mostly happens by making new commits.  Meanwhile, `git rebase` means *I'm sort of satisfied with some set of commits in my repository, but there is something I don't like about these commits.  I'd like to copy them to a set of new-and-improved commits, with the option of doing special tricks along the way.*

Because you literally can't *change* any existing commit, the copying means that you get duplicates—or rather, near-duplicates, with the "near" part depending on what you're changing, given that you're changing *something* or you'd just *use* the originals.  The goal of rebase is to *stop using the originals* and start using the near-duplicates instead.  Since we generally *find* our commits using a *branch name*, Git achieves this by *moving the name:*

```
             K--L   <-- br2 (originals)
            /
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- br1
                  \
                   K'-L'  <-- proposed new br2

<-- older ... newer -->
```

We have Git copy `K` to `K'`, improving the copy by using `J` as the base commit, then we have Git copy `L` to `L'`, improving the copy by using `K'` as the base for `L'`.  That's the main part of the rebase in action.  But now we have to *stop using* `K-L`, and start using `K'-L'` instead.  Since we *find* commits through *branch names*, Git merely needs to "peel the label" off commit `L` and paste it onto commit `L'` instead.  Git then works backwards—this is a general theme in Git, that it starts at the end and works its way backwards—from `L'`, so now you don't *see* `K-L` any more.

Because *commits* are shared and *branch names aren't*, if you *got* commits `K-L` from some *other Git repository*, you now have a problem: *their* branch name still refers to commit `L`, not to your new `L'`.

#### `git push` is not just a reversed `git fetch`

When you run `git push`, you:

- have your Git call up some other Git;
- have your Git give that Git *specific* commits: not just *everything I have that you don't* but rather *every commit **on some branch** that I have that you don't* (commits I have that you don't, that are on some particular branch of my choice);
- and finally, once those commits have made it over, you politely request (regular `git push`) or command (`git push --force`) that *their* Git should update *their branch name*.

When we use `git fetch`, we have these friendly remote-tracking names by which our Git remembers their branch names.  The `push` command doesn't bother with friendliness.  We just propose to overwrite their branch name entirely, with some new hash ID.

If the commits we send to them *add on* to their branch as they see it right then and there, this polite request—*please set your branch name `develop` to `a123456...`* for instance—is probably OK.  They had:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop
```

where `H` stands in for `9876543...` or whatever hash ID.  We sent them commits `I-J`:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   <-- polite request to set "develop" to point to J
```

If they obey this polite request, their commit `H` remains findable, because Git works backwards from the branch name's commit.  `J` leads back to `I` which leads back to `H`, and hey, we haven't lost them any commits!

After a `git rebase`, though, we've taken some existing commits and thrown them out in favor of new-and-improved replacements.  Suppose they had:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

in *their* repository, and we now send them a pair of commits `K'-L'` that add on to commit `J`:

```
                  K'-L'   <-- please set br2 here
                 /
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

This polite request, that they set their `br2` to point to `L'` instead of `L`, will not go over well.  They will say: *No! If I do that I lose commits!*  Of course, we *want* them to lose `K-L`, in favor of `K'-L'`.  But they don't know that unless we tell them.

This is what `git push --force` is for.  However, if their Git repository is highly active, maybe we *got* `K-L` earlier, but now they have:

```
                  K'-L'   <-- please set br2 here
                 /
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
            \
             K--L--N   <-- br2
```

We're proposing that they ditch the entire `K-L-N` chain in favor of our `K'-L'`.

The `--force-with-lease` option is an attempt to improve this situation.  It works pretty well in current Git, but there may be updates coming where it won't be quite right.  (I think it should be kept "right", and there are proposals to do that too, so we'll see.)

#### Bare repositories

When we use Git, we have some commit *checked out*.  This commit is from our *current branch* and is our *current commit*.  We may be in the middle of working on a new commit.  In this state, Git literally *can't* receive an update to our current branch: that would mess things up.<sup>6</sup>  So Git will deny a push to the currently-checked-out branch.

To sidestep this problem, Git repositories that are *meant* to receive `git push` requests are normally set up as *bare* repositories.  A bare repository is one with no working tree.  With no working tree, no one can do any work in the bare repository.  This means there is nothing to get messed up, and the bare repository can always receive a push.

There are other ways to deal with this (configuration settings for `receive.denyCurrentBranch`), but another good way to sidestep the problem is to *avoid* `git push`: use `git fetch` when using two different repositories where you control both of them.  By always fetching from B when you're in working in A, and always fetching from A when you're working in B, you *can't* step on yourself.

---

<sup>6</sup>In particular, Git's *index* contains an image of the current commit, as modified by any proposed replacement files we `git add`-ed, new files we added, and/or files we `git rm`-ed.  Git will build the new commit from whatever is in the index, and the parent of the new commit will be the current commit, whose hash ID is stored in the branch name.  So making an update to the *branch name* requires updating the *index and working tree* as well.  If we're in the middle of doing something, that's a bad idea.  Even if we're not, updating the branch name means that our new commit may go where we didn't expect.  The whole situation is tough.

#### A bottom line

In Git, you work locally, with *commits*.  These are in *your repository:* there's just the one, which you're in right now, with the one working tree and Git's index.<sup>7</sup>  To get commits from some other Git, use `git fetch` with a *remote:* a short name like `origin`.  Add more remotes, with `git remote add`, to add more places to fetch *from*.  Use `git remote set-url` to fiddle with the URL for one particular remote, `git remote remove` to remove a remote, and `git remote update` to make Git fetch from *all* remotes.<sup>8</sup>  Consider setting `fetch.prune` to `true` to work around what I consider a historical error in the `fetch` defaults.<sup>9</sup>

After you `git fetch`, you have *all* the commits.  Do whatever you like with them.  Leave them in your repository, rebase them, whatever.  Then, if the other Git is a *bare* Git that's set up to receive `git push` requests, use `git push` to send your new commits and ask them to set one of their *branch* names to remember your commits:

- If this creates a *new name* in their Git, they'll probably allow it.
- If this updates a name such that the old commits are still there, they'll probably allow it.
- If this updates a name so as to *stop finding* old commits on their side, they will reject it unless you use one of the `--force` options; use `--force-with-lease` for safety.

If the other Git *isn't* bare, and/or you want to work directly in it, change where you're working so that you're now in the *other* repository, and use `git fetch` to obtain the commits you made in the repository you *were* working in, a moment ago.  Since `fetch` itself is always safe,<sup>10</sup> this will be safe.

Always, **always** remember that if you haven't *committed* something, it's not *in Git* (yet).  If you have *committed* it, it's in a commit, and even after mini-disasters, you can usually get it back.<sup>11</sup>

---

<sup>7</sup>`git worktree add` complicates this picture, so let's just ignore it here.

<sup>8</sup>Or, use `git fetch --all`: this is what `--all` means, *all remotes*.  The `git remote update` command is fancier and lets you do more stuff here though.

<sup>9</sup>That is, run:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

once, to set this in your global configuration, on this particular machine.  When `git fetch` fetches from some remote R, it creates or updates `R/branch` for each branch it sees on R.  But if R had a branch named `fancy42` yesterday and today that branch is *gone*, your Git doesn't do anything: it created `fancy42` yesterday when you ran `git fetch`, and now there's no `fancy42` to create or update, so it doesn't create or update it.  That leaves you with a "stale" `fancy42`.

With *pruning* enabled, `git fetch` and `git remote update` notice that their `fancy42` is gone now, and therefore you shouldn't have `R/fancy42` either.  Your Git will delete this.  This isn't the default because, well, it wasn't the default originally, and now it's too late to change it.  There may be people who like or even depend on it.  If you like it yourself, leave `fetch.prune` set to `false` and don't run `git remote prune`.

<sup>10</sup>You can configure or force `git fetch` to be "unsafe", but unless you do that on purpose or use `git clone --mirror` to do that, you won't run into this.

<sup>11</sup>The big exception to this rule is if the Git databases themselves get damaged.  This tends to happen when:

- the repository is on a shared drive (Google Drive, iCloud, OneDrive, etc);
- the computer crashes or is shut down improperly so that the OS fails to write stuff to disk;
- the computer itself catches on fire (this was once a common laptop problem); or
- you use the OS to forcibly remove the Git repository database inside the `.git` directory.

Otherwise these things are really quite reliable.

Comment: Thank you. A great quick-through of some concepts. Truly appreciate that.