# Git post-receive hook is not working

Tags: git

I work with Git 1.95 (local) and 1.71 (remote). I've read all of the threads on Git hooks that don't work, but I haven't found a solution yet.

What's happening:
I have set a remote non-bare repository to which I push from the local repo through ssh. The post-receive hook is very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
touch worked.txt
```

I added the necessary permissions with `chmod +x`, and it works when executed manually.  I ended up reading [this](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/),  but still I don't have a solution. This should be very simple, but instead it's very frustrating.

Comment: Did you put the hook in your `non-bare repo/.git/hooks/post-receive`?

Comment: The hook's address is ~/public_html/.git/hooks/post-receive

Comment: Do you have a `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch` set to `true` on that `public_html` repo? Because only a git 2.3.0 would allow more easily a push to a non-bare repo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309.

Comment: Indeed, the receive.denyCurrentBranch is set to warn