# Git receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead fails

Tags: git, ssh, web-deployment

I'm brand new to git and have no experience with any version control system.  I develop locally and am looking for a simpler way (than FTP) to deploy files to the (LAMP) web server. I am having a hard time configuring Git (version 2.5 for Windows) to automatically update its current working directory when I push changes. Here is what I've done, after creating a local repo, doing the first commit, and adding the remote location under alias `origin`:

1. [remote] `ssh user@domain`
2. [remote] `cd testgit`
3. [remote] `git init`
4. [remote] `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead`
5. [remote] `git status`: nothing to commit
6. [remote] `exit`
7. [local >> master] `git status`: nothing added but untracked files present
8. [local >> master] `git push origin master`

Step 8 generates one notice and two errors:

- `stdin: is not a tty`
- `fatal: bad config value for 'receive.denycurrentbranch' in config`
- `fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

I've been looking around but I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created any commits at all?

Comment: Yes I did the first commit locally before trying to push. I wrote so in the OP, just before the list of steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you would need to add and commit before pushing: if you have untracked files, then won't be pushed until you do add and commit.

Second, "receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead" [is only for git 2.3+ (February 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309): make sure you have the right version of git n the server side.

> Should git be installed separately on the server? I have git 2.5 on my Windows machine. I did not install anything specifically on the server

Yes you need to have git on the server as well.

Comment: I did my first commit locally. I wrote so in the OP, just above step 1.  Am I not allowed to have any untracked files?  Re: Second: Should git be installed separately on the server?  I have git 2.5 on my Windows machine. I did not install anything specifically on the server.

Comment: Thanks. I ran `git --version` on the server. Version is 1.8.3.  I'll look into how to upgrade git, then test my initial steps again.

Comment: @Patrick I confirm: 1.8.3 won't support `updateInstead` for the `receive.denyCurrentBranch`.

Comment: After upgrading git on the server to 2.4, things worked as expected. My initial problem is that I did not realize that git was also running on the server. I thought local git was controlling everything.

Comment: @Patrick git is purely a local filesystem manager (able to manage the history of files). Unless you access the server through a shared path, you would need another git to execute git command on the server side.