# How do I run a different version of git on a server?

Tags: git, version

I have a git repository on a server with an old version of git (1.7.1). I need a feature only available starting in git 2.3, namely I want to run the command:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

After talking with the sysadmin, they installed a recent version of git (2.27.0) in a different location on the server. Using this newer version, I was able to run the above command for the repository.

However, whenever I push from my local machine to the server, I get the following error message:

```
fatal: bad config value for 'receive.denycurrentbranch' in ./config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This seems to suggest that when I `push` to the server, the server defaults to running the old version of git. Is there a way to tell the server to run git from a different exec-path? When running

```
git --exec-path=/path/to/new/git/env
```

I am met with strange errors like git ignoring everything after the `exec-path`, or ignoring all the flags altogether. I am not sure if the `--exec-path` flag is even the right approach to this problem.

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990207/fatal-bad-config-value-for-receive-denycurrentbranch-in-config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the new [`git-upload-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack)/[`git-receive-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack)

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git config remote.origin.uploadpack /path/to/new/git/usr/bin/git-upload-pack
git config remote.origin.receivepack /path/to/new/git/usr/bin2/git-receive-pack
```

That would be a good start for making sure git push/pull talk to the right Git.