# How do I configure a remote to have a fixed receive pack?

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks, git-post-receive, git-bare

I have a git bare repository on my server which has a post-receive hook that essentially does

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=`/path/to/public_html` git checkout -f
```

Whenever I do a push from my local repo to this remote I get an error:

```
fatal: bad config value for 'receive.denycurrentbranch' in ./config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

I found [a solution for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62788948/997147) which works fine. However, I cannot expect to type out the `--exec=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git-receive-pack` each time I make a push. I know one option would be to make an alias to the whole command but that doesn't work great either since when I shift to a different system I need to have this command as well.

How do I go about enforcing that the right receive pack is used? The issue seems to be that [I'm using a shared hosting which uses cPanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git+-+Host+Git+Repositories+on+a+cPanel+Account#GuidetoGit-HostGitRepositoriesonacPanelAccount-Pushlocalchangestothehostedrepository.). Is there anything I can specify on my bare repo to ensure I can normally do `git push origin master` rather than specifying the pack? Or something that can be done on client side and stored into the main repo also works--as long as when I clone back the repo on another system I can continue using it normally. Suggestions?

Comment: [`git config remote.<name>.receivepack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtreceivepack)

Comment: Yes, I had seen this one but it doesn't seem like something that can be stored in github and restored automatically during a clone.