# Can I push a local repo to another repo?

Tags: git

I'm learning git and just experimenting, so there is not real reason I need to do this yet:

I tried running

> git push path_to_local_repo master

form a different local repository.

I got this error:

[image]

Why is git angry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this Git warning message when pushing changes to a remote repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804545/what-is-this-git-warning-message-when-pushing-changes-to-a-remote-repository)

Comment: The error message quite clearly states:
"Refusing to update checked out branch"

Ie. you need to check out another branch and then the operation would be possible, but a bit silly, as you'd be pushing the master branch onto itself. It would just say "Everything up to date"

Comment: I believe the correct method will be to just copy the files. A repo is a directory, and it's scope is not aware of other repos on the filesystem. Interesting question though!

Comment: I'm sure if it can be aware of remote repos it can be aware of local repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to push to the currently checked-out branch in the other local git repo.  Possible work-arounds: push to a different branch and then manually merge that branch into master

```
git push ~/root-working master:godaddy-master
cd ~/root-working
git merge --ff-only godaddy-master
```

or just go into the other folder and pull from there

```
cd ~/root-working
git pull ~/root-godaddy
```

Comment: but it is completely O.K. to push and pull from non-bare repos I take it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Git only doesn't want anybody to get confused, as the checked out files could be different than what's in the repo.  So it just plain refuses to push.

Comment: But still this is why bare repos are normally use to share files.

Answer (score 0):

You want to push a local repo to another remote repo, right?

If so:

```
git push [remote] branch_name
```

Comment: Nope local to local, I'm just testing things.