# Deploy code from local to server without runnning pull command on server side

Tags: git, deployment, gitlab, localserver

I have a local machine and a server. I am using GitLab. Anytime I deploy my code from local, I wish to automatically deploy my code on server machine. Currently the issue that I am facing is, when I am deploying code from local to server(SSH), I have to login to my server to pull the changes and see. I dont want to run "pull command". How can I do without running pull command ?

Comment: By "server" do you mean Gitlab? Or do you have three locations: workstation, GitLab, deployment server?

Comment: Why do you want to deploy without `git pull`?

Answer (score 1):

You could push to your server (instead of login and pulling)

If you have git 2.4+ on your server, go to your repo on your server and type:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead
```

You can then push (always the same branch) and your repo will be updated directly.
See "[What is this Git warning message when pushing changes to a remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309)"