# Attempts to push Spring Boot to Git repository fails

Tags: eclipse, git, spring-boot

I have a working Spring Boot application that I created in Eclipse that I wold like to put into a new Git repository.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to do this using Eclipse (or any other Git tool).

I am using Eclipse v2019-06 (4.12.0) and the Spring Tool Suite (STS) v4.3.1

To illustrate the problem, I take the following steps:

I create the Spring Boot project using STS:

```
Click on "Create a Project"->"Spring Boot"->"Spring Starter Project"
```

Project name is GitProject

Nothing fancy in this project. Createed a HelloController class that returned some HTML. Ran a browser to test it and displayed a "greeting" web page.

Compile project
    mvnw clean package

Successful compile. Ran and successfully displayed web page:
      java -jar GitProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

The project is successful and the service works. Place project into Git

There are procedures described to create and push to new repositories. Based on procedures provided in Stack Overflow answers, perform the following:

1. Create the repository
   git init
2. Make it bare
   git init --bare
3. Create a basic README file for adding to the repository
   echo Testing > README
4. Add and commit the README file
   git add README
   git commit -m "Initial Code"

Now put the project into the repository. Or at least, attempt to...

1. Create a project in a different folder, importing from the new repository 
   Click on "Import projects..."->"Projects from Git"

Clone the URI from the new repository, Only the master branch is available. Place the destination in the project folder. Because there is no existing project in the new repo, and since the IDE does not offer a way to successfully create a new Spring Boot project from a repo (I made several attempts to use the New Project Wizard to create an STS project when creating the repo. Every attempt led to different Exceptions being thrown while creating the project), select "Import as General Project" in the "Select a Wizard" dialog.

2. Go to the folder with the original GitProject project. Copy everything from that folder and paste it onto the new project
3. Edit the .gitignore file that gets included in the Spring Boot project. It is important to remove all references to the STS files except for the .sts4-cache file. These need to be saved at least once in order to ensure that the Spring Boot information is saved in the repository.
4. Right- click on the project and select Team->Commit
5. Stage everything, enter a commit message, then click on "Commit and Push"

   See the following failure:

   master-master [remote rejected]
    Repository

   branch is currently checked out
   error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
   error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
   is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
   with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
   the work tree to HEAD.

   You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
   to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
   its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
   arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
   other way.

   To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
   'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.

What is strange is that somehow this branch remains "checked out" after being cloned but the IDE does not appear to provide a way to "check it back in". Worse: I actually tried just cloning the new repo, changing the README file, then committing and pushing it (without including the Spring Boot code) and that attempt yielded the same failure.

So how do I get this code committed and pushed into my repository? What step is missing from the documentation of how to do this???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this Git warning message when pushing changes to a remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804545/what-is-this-git-warning-message-when-pushing-changes-to-a-remote-repository)

Comment: So you have two local repositories, a bare one you can't work on (probably supposed to emulate a remote upstream repository) and a non-bare one with a working tree to work in (as the real local repository), right? Is that what you're trying to do?