# gitosis and git clone problem

Tags: git, version-control, gitosis

I have installed gitosis, but i have strange thing when i'm working with repos.
In config i have

```
[gitosis]

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin
members = me@server me@laptop

[group prj1]
writable = prj1
members = me@laptop
```

and in /home/git/repositories i have created directory prj1.git with empty git repo.

i can work with gitosis-admin from server and laptop without problems, but when i'm trying to *git clone* prj1 on my laptop i see

```
$ git clone git@server:prj1.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/alec/temp/prj1/.git/
fatal: no matching remote head
```

ok, lets push prj1 from laptop to server:

```
$ git push origin master:refs/heads/master
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would the following, done on your laptop, solve this issue?
Instead of a git clone:

```
  mkdir prj1
  cd prj1
  git init
  touch README
  git add .
  git commit -m "Added blank readme"
  git remote add origin git@server:prj1.git
  git push origin master
```

[ebneter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150032/ebneter) adds in the comment:

> You might mention that **the reason this works is that you can't clone an empty repo**.
>   (As my users regularly discover...

And that reminds the OP question:

> ... and in `/home/git/repositories` I have created directory prj1.git with *empty git repo*

which is not ideal right there.
This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895819/whats-the-most-straightforward-way-to-clone-an-empty-bare-git-repository) mentions the issue of cloning an empty repo:

> In other words, don't attempt to clone the empty repo, but rather after creating it, push to it a simple repo containing one innocuous file. Then it is no longer empty and can be cloned.

---

Since then, [Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen) comments:

> Any Git later than 1.6.2

(so actually since March 2009)

> can “clone” empty repositories.
>   (scare quotes because it really just amounts normal initialization plus setting up a remote, and creating a tracking configuration for the presumed, eventual master branch).

Comment: Any Git later than 1.6.2 can “clone” empty repositories (scare quotes because it really just amounts normal initialization plus setting up a remote, and creating a tracking configuration for the presumed, eventual master branch).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem which persisted even after following the steps in Answer 1.

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update
```

solved it for me. Apparently older versions of setuptools can make the post-update hook non-executable. Refer [this page](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same message, after I want to push to a new repository:

```
git push -u origin master
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The reason was that I had 2 same ssh pub-keys (same key, different name) in gitosis-admin/keydir.

After deleting one of it, I can push to new repositories

Comment: Make sure o remove one of them from ~gitosis/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, the reason was that I edited gitosis.conf on my local and did not commit it to server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ssh client picked the wrong private key from ~/.ssh.

[gitosis] loglevel = DEBUG helped seeing that the wrong user was being logged in.