# Git force complete sync to master

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

My workplace uses Subversion for source control so I have been playing around with git-svn for the advantages of my own branches, commit as often as I want without touching the main repo, etc.

Since my git svn checkout is local, I have cloned it to a network share as well to act as a backup. My thinking is that if my desktop takes a dump I will at least have the repo on the network share to get changes that I have not had a chance to dcommit yet.

My workflow is to work from the desktop, make changes, commit, etc. At the end of the day I want to update the repo on the network share with all of my current changes. I had setup the repo on the network share using `git clone repo_on_my_desktop` and then updating the repo on the network share with `git pull origin master`. The problem that I am running into is when I used do a `git rebase` to squish multiple commits prior to dcommitting to the main svn repository. When I do this, I get merge conflicts on the repo on the network share when I try to backup at night.

Is there a way to simply sync entirely with the repository on my desktop without doing a new `git clone` each night?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two comments:

1/ I would recommend having either [bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041823/git-how-to-see-pulled-pushed-changes-in-origin/2041865#2041865) or a [bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545765/how-can-i-email-someone-a-git-repository/2545784#2545784) (one file, easier to move around) for your network share

2/ I would rather add network_repo as a remote to your desktop repo and push from there (`git push --force network_repo master`): you stay in your working repo.

Answer (score 56):

You shouldn't be doing a rebase if you intend to pull from another repo.

If you don't mind overriding changes in your network share, you can do this:

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will reset the local master to the origin master.

**Warning**: this is a *hard* reset, it will lose all your changes (committed* or not).

But I'm assuming you don't really have any changes there, and it's mostly just a backup.

* Note: technically speaking, committed changes are not lost until they expire from the reflog, but for all intents and purposes, they're effectively lost.

Comment: No it does not remove the extraneous files.

Comment: If you have any changes and happy to lose them, you also need `git clean -f -d`. This should ensure complete sync.