# Git: show total file size difference between two commits?

Tags: git, filesize, git-diff

Is it possible to show the total file size difference between two commits? Something like:

```
$ git file-size-diff 7f3219 bad418 # I wish this worked :)
-1234 bytes
```

I’ve tried:

```
$ git diff --patch-with-stat
```

And that shows the file size difference for each *binary* file in the diff — but not for text files, and not the total file size difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the 3-lines bashscript giving you size of certain commit http://stackoverflow.com/a/23985353/2062041

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`git cat-file -s` will output the size in bytes of an object in git. `git diff-tree` can tell you the differences between one tree and another.

Putting this together into a script called `git-file-size-diff` located somewhere on your PATH will give you the ability to call `git file-size-diff <tree-ish> <tree-ish>`. We can try something like the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
USAGE='[--cached] [<rev-list-options>...]

Show file size changes between two commits or the index and a commit.'

SUBDIRECTORY_OK=1
. "$(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup"
args=$(git rev-parse --sq "$@")
[ -n "$args" ] || usage
cmd="diff-tree -r"
[[ $args =~ "--cached" ]] && cmd="diff-index"
eval "git $cmd $args" | {
  total=0
  while read A B C D M P
  do
    case $M in
      M) bytes=$(( $(git cat-file -s $D) - $(git cat-file -s $C) )) ;;
      A) bytes=$(git cat-file -s $D) ;;
      D) bytes=-$(git cat-file -s $C) ;;
      *)
        echo >&2 warning: unhandled mode $M in \"$A $B $C $D $M $P\"
        continue
        ;;
    esac
    total=$(( $total + $bytes ))
    printf '%d\t%s\n' $bytes "$P"
  done
  echo total $total
}
```

In use this looks like the following:

```bash
$ git file-size-diff HEAD~850..HEAD~845
-234   Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.7.txt
112    Documentation/git.txt
-4     GIT-VERSION-GEN
43     builtin/grep.c
42     diff-lib.c
594    git-rebase--interactive.sh
381    t/t3404-rebase-interactive.sh
114    t/test-lib.sh
743    tree-walk.c
28     tree-walk.h
67     unpack-trees.c
28     unpack-trees.h
total 1914
```

By using `git-rev-parse` it should accept all the usual ways of specifying commit ranges.

EDIT: updated to record the cumulative total. Note that bash runs the while read in a subshell, hence the additional curly braces to avoid losing the total when the subshell exits.

EDIT: added support for comparing the index against another tree-ish by using a `--cached` argument to call `git diff-index` instead of `git diff-tree`. eg:

```bash
$ git file-size-diff --cached master
-570    Makefile
-134    git-gui.sh
-1  lib/browser.tcl
931 lib/commit.tcl
18  lib/index.tcl
total 244
```

EDIT: Mark script as capable of running in a subdirectory of a git repository.

Comment: +1 Thanks! This would be *absolutely* perfect if it would print out the total size difference at the bottom. I want to see how many bytes were added/removed project-wide between two refs (not just per file, but in total, too).

Comment: Another question: why are you sourcing `git-sh-setup` here? You don’t seem to be using [any of the functions it defines](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-sh-setup.html). Just wondering!

Comment: It does basic checks like producing a sensible message if you run this command in a directory that is not a git repository. It also can help abstract out some platform differences. Mostly habit though. When writing a git script - first bring in the git-sh-setup file.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome script! I was looking for someway to monitor the increase of size after each commit and this helps a lot. I made a small gist to show only the total increase between all (some of) the commits in the repository https://gist.github.com/iamaziz/1019e5a9261132ac2a9a  thanks again!

Comment: The use case I'm looking for is to preview large commits before I make them. Is there a way I can find the size changes of the currently staged changes?
I've read through the tree-ish documentation, and I could not find a way to reference "current staged changes".

Comment: Added support for comparing against the index using `git-diff-index`.

Comment: you can run `echo $PATH` to see your path directories to see where you can put this script file.  I put mine in `/usr/local/git/bin` and it worked great.  You can also add a path to your `$PATH` if you want to put the script somewhere else.

Comment: How do I use this? What is `HEAD~850`? Can I just use instead the commit id?

Comment: @mr5 HEAD~850 is 850 commits before HEAD. It is just another notation for a commit and yes you can use a specific commit id or a tag or anything that can be resolved to a commit. The script uses `git rev-parse` so see the manual section "Specifying Revisions" in the git-rev-parse documentation for the full details. (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)

Comment: How would i be able to see what size the files had before? I am currently preparing a pull request that optimizes file output structure and would like to calculate a percentage of size decrease.

Comment: That looks great! Any way to make it work on Windows?

Comment: This works on windows. Create the file in a directory that is on your PATH.

Comment: Great script! Very useful. I've added it to my [git-filesize-diff.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/git-filesize-diff.sh) file in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo. You can see the output from my modified version of your script [in my commit message here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/commit/05ce8b1476a1ebbe7f694b808da8cfe886abf64a).

Comment: Nice script. However the `$(git cat-file -s $D) - $(git cat-file -s $C)` construct is problematic in the sense that it shows only the file size delta, not the file data delta. For example, you could have a file of 1024 bytes that has its content replace by different 1024 bytes, then the `$(git cat-file -s $D) - $(git cat-file -s $C)` construct would calculate a delta of 0 bytes, while the actual data delta is 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 30):

You can pipe the out put of

```
git show some-ref:some-path-to-file | wc -c
git show some-other-ref:some-path-to-file | wc -c
```

and compare the 2 numbers.

Comment: +1 This is great for quickly checking the size difference of a file between versions. But how can this be used to get the total file difference between two commits? I want to see how many bytes were added/removed project-wide between two refs.

Comment: You can skip the `| wc -c` if you use `cat-file -s` instead of `show`

Comment: Using the improvement suggested by @neu242, I wrote this bash function:

`gdbytes () { echo "$(git cat-file -s $1:$3) -> $(git cat-file -s $2:$3)" }`

Which makes it easy to see how file size changed since last commit with e.g., `gdbytes @~ @ index.html`

Comment: if the `some-ref:` part is skipped, do you obtain the file size in the working directory?

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [matthiaskrgr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077961/1677912), https://github.com/matthiaskrgr/gitdiffbinstat can be used like the other scripts:

```
gitdiffbinstat.sh HEAD..HEAD~4
```

Imo it really works well, much faster than anything else posted here. Sample output:

```
$ gitdiffbinstat.sh HEAD~6..HEAD~7
 HEAD~6..HEAD~7
 704a8b56161d8c69bfaf0c3e6be27a68f27453a6..40a8563d082143d81e622c675de1ea46db706f22
 Recursively getting stat for path "./c/data/gitrepo" from repo root......
 105 files changed in total
  3 text files changed, 16 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-) => [±0 lines]
  102 binary files changed 40374331 b (38 Mb) -> 39000258 b (37 Mb) => [-1374073 b (-1 Mb)]
   0 binary files added, 3 binary files removed, 99 binary files modified => [-3 files]
    0 b  added in new files, 777588 b (759 kb) removed => [-777588 b (-759 kb)]
    file modifications: 39596743 b (37 Mb) -> 39000258 b (37 Mb) => [-596485 b (-582 kb)]
    / ==>  [-1374073 b (-1 Mb)]
```

The output directory is funky with ./c/data... as /c is actually the filesytem root.

Comment: You didn't need to comment on Matthias' post - you could have suggested an edit to it instead, with these details that he didn't provide. By current standards, his answer would be considered a "link-only answer", and be deleted, so these sorts of details are important.

Comment: who can take my answer and include it into matthias?

Comment: If you want, you can make a suggested edit yourself. (In my experience, it would tend to get get rejected by reviewers, but a clear explanation in the Edit Summary could help.) But maybe I wasn't clear in my comment to you... your answer is a stand-alone answer, a good update of Matthias' older answer. You didn't need to include the text that explained that you meant to comment, is all. I edited the answer in a way that gives appropriate credit to Matthias. You don't need to do more.

Answer (score 3):

I made a bash script to compare branches/commits etc by actual file/content size.
It can be found at https://github.com/matthiaskrgr/gitdiffbinstat and also detects file renames.

Comment: Got an example usage of this?

Answer (score 2):

A comment to the script: git-file-size-diff, suggested by patthoyts. The script is very useful, however, I have found two issues:

1. When someone change permissions on the file, git returns a another type in the case statement:

   ```
   T) echo >&2 "Skipping change of type"
   continue ;;
   ```
2. If a sha-1 value doesn't exist anymore (for some reason), the script crashes. You need to validate the sha before getting the file size:

   `$(git cat-file -e $D)
    if [ "$?" = 1 ]; then continue; fi`

The complete case statement will then look like this:

```
case $M in
      M) $(git cat-file -e $D)
         if [ "$?" = 1 ]; then continue; fi
         $(git cat-file -e $C)
         if [ "$?" = 1 ]; then continue; fi
         bytes=$(( $(git cat-file -s $D) - $(git cat-file -s $C) )) ;;
      A) $(git cat-file -e $D)
         if [ "$?" = 1 ]; then continue; fi
         bytes=$(git cat-file -s $D) ;;
      D) $(git cat-file -e $C)
         if [ "$?" = 1 ]; then continue; fi
         bytes=-$(git cat-file -s $C) ;;
      T) echo >&2 "Skipping change of type"
         continue ;;
      *)
        echo >&2 warning: unhandled mode $M in \"$A $B $C $D $M $P\"
        continue
        ;;
    esac
```

Answer (score 1):

The Git core commands can make this *much* more efficient, instead of the postprocessing being three commands per blob it's three commands total:

```bash
filesizediffs() {
    git diff-tree "$@" \
    | awk '$1":"$2 ~ /:[10]0....:[10]0/ {
            print $3?$3:empty,substr($5,3)
            print $4?$4:empty,substr($5,3)
      }'  FS='[  ]' empty=`git hash-object -w --stdin <&-` \
    | git cat-file --batch-check=$'%(objectsize)\t%(rest)' \
    |  awk '!seen[$2]++ { first[$2]=$1 }
            $1!=first[$2] { print $1-first[$2],$2; total+=$1-first[$2] }
            END { print "total size difference "total }' FS=$'\t' OFS=$'\t'
}
filesizediffs @
```

on GNU/anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re happy with an approximate answer, you can get a back-of-napkin size of the data in a commit with:

```
git archive <COMMIT> | wc -c
```

The reported size will be the number of bytes of all the data in the commit plus some tar metadata. Since `tar` by itself (the default for `git archive`) doesn’t do compression the reported numbers are somewhat comparable.

If your intent is to find the one commit that added the 1GB log file, this approach is perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, diff size (when dealing with source code) is meant as the number of added and removed lines. That is, size is judged according to the cognitive load imposed on a hypothetical reviewer of the commit. This takes into account that deletions are usually easier to review than additions.

### `git diff --shortstat`

```
$ git diff --shortstat HEAD~5 HEAD
9 files changed, 117 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)
```

### `git diff --stat`

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD~5 HEAD
 .../java/org/apache/calcite/rex/RexSimplify.java   | 50 +++++++++++++++++-----
 .../apache/calcite/sql/fun/SqlTrimFunction.java    |  2 +-
 .../apache/calcite/sql2rel/SqlToRelConverter.java  | 16 +++++++
 .../org/apache/calcite/util/SaffronProperties.java | 19 ++++----
 .../org/apache/calcite/test/RexProgramTest.java    | 24 +++++++++++
 .../apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.java |  8 ++++
 .../apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.xml  | 15 +++++++
 pom.xml                                            |  2 +-
 .../apache/calcite/adapter/spark/SparkRules.java   |  7 +--
 9 files changed, 117 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)
```

### `git diff --numstat`

```
$ git diff --numstat HEAD~5 HEAD
40      10      core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/rex/RexSimplify.java
1       1       core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql/fun/SqlTrimFunction.java
16      0       core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql2rel/SqlToRelConverter.java
8       11      core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/util/SaffronProperties.java
24      0       core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/RexProgramTest.java
8       0       core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.java
15      0       core/src/test/resources/org/apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.xml
1       1       pom.xml
4       3       spark/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/adapter/spark/SparkRules.java
```

Source of the usage examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839441/1047788