# How to log total diff size of commits in git?

Tags: git

Is there a simple way to show total size of changed code, not just number of commits, like

*`git shortlog -n -s`* do ?

Preferably with option to filter create/remove diffs.

Comment: Possibly answered by http://stackoverflow.com/a/10847242/291641

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly you want, but you can try `git diff --shortstat HEAD~10..HEAD~5`, the result is like this:

```
27 files changed, 1431 insertions(+), 592 deletions(-)
```