# get size of commit from github api

Tags: git, github

I've been looking through the Github API trying to work out it there's a simple way to get the size of a commit, i.e. what's the amount of change that took place:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

My google and stackoverflow searches turned up:

[Git: show total file size difference between two commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845051/git-show-total-file-size-difference-between-two-commits)

and a few other command line options, but I wonder if anyone knows of a good way to do this through the Github API?

Many thanks in advance