# git-p4 submit fails with "Not a valid object name HEAD~261"

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I've got a git repository that I'd like to mirror to a Perforce repository. I've downloaded the git-p4 script (the more recent version that doesn't give deprecation warnings), and have been working with that. I've figured out how to pull changes from Perforce, but I'm getting an error when I try to sync changes from the git repo back. Here's what I've done so far:

```
git clone git@github.com:asdf/qwerty.git
git-p4 sync //depot/path/to/querty
git merge remotes/p4/master     (there was a single README file...)
```

So, I've copied the origin to a clean, new director, got a lovely looking merged tree of files, and `git status` shows I'm up-to-date. But:

```
> git-p4 submit
fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD~261
Command failed: git cat-file commit HEAD~261
```

[This thread on the git mailing list](http://lists-archives.org/git/715445-git-p4-and-git-clone.html) seems to be relevant, but I can't figure out what they're doing with all the A, B, and Cs. Could someone please clarify what "Not a valid object name" means, and what I can do to fix the problem? All I want to do is to periodically snapshot the origin/master into Perforce; a full history is not required. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, I have an existing codebase in a git repo (stored on github, not that that matters), and a Perforce repo that is empty. I want to make periodic snapshots of my git repo's master branch to the Perforce repo. All of the git-p4 examples I've seen assume that the Perforce repo is primary and that I'm creating a new git repo. That's not the case for me. I don't want to change the existing git project in any way, but the instructions in the mailing list and VonC's response assume new work is in this strange double-clone new repo.

Comment: I ma sorry your bounty didn't work. May be a new question with a different context or different details might help.

Comment: Thread on mailing list sounded like it has some good info in it, but link is broken and neither google's cache or archive.org have a copy.

Comment: Are there any news how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

9 years later, that issue might be gone with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)

See [commit c3f2358](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3f2358de39a8ac754ae68880a992835a84a6f0c) (28 May 2019) by [Mike Mueller (`mdymike`)](https://github.com/mdymike).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit add59c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/add59c4708cd629a6ee3175f0e0a796cc9b6db28), 17 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `p4 unshelve`: fix "`Not a valid object name HEAD0`" on Windows
>
> `git p4 unshelve` was failing with these errors:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD0
Command failed: git cat-file commit HEAD^0

(git version 2.21.0.windows.1, python 2.7.16)
```

> The `pOpen` call used by `git-p4` to invoke the `git` command can take either a
>   string or an array as a first argument.
>   The array form is preferred because platform-specific escaping of special characters will be handled automatically.(https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)
>   The `extractLogMessageFromGitCommit` method was, however, using the string
>   form and so the caret (`^`) character in the `HEAD^`0 argument was not being
>   escaped on Windows.
>   The caret happens to be the escape character, which is why the git command was receiving `HEAD0`.
>
> The behaviour can be confirmed by typing `ECHO HEAD^0` at the command-
>   prompt, which emits `HEAD0`.
>
> The solution is simply to use the array format of passing the command to `fOpen`, which is recommended and used in other parts of this code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
fatal: Not a valid object name
```

should mean that somehow the remote's HEAD points to an incorrect reference.
In other word, when you do a P4 import in a git repo, there is no way to submit from that git repo to P4, because of an incorrect SHA1. Why? I don't know.

That is why, in the thread you mention, the user:

- clone the P4 repo into B with `--import-local` ("Import into `refs/heads/`, not `refs/remotes`"),
- [make B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/git-convert-normal-to-bare-repository) (the Git clone of the p4 repo) a [bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean/738249#738249) (so you won't ever work in it, since its working tree is empty)
- fix the `HEAD` of B to reference the p4 master branch imported in B
- clone B into C, a non-bare repo (its working tree is not empty, you can work in it)

B was only there for the initial import.

The rest of the work is done in C (which has no issue of incorrect SHA1) with:

- `git-p4 sync`  (to declare in C `remotes/p4/master` in addition to `remotes/origin/*`)
- `git-p4 submit`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you please try again? Thanks.

Comment: @Harlan: I have emphasized the role of repo `C`. I do not fully understand the *exact* cause of this issue, but I just wanted to illustrate the workaround proposed in the thread you mention.

Comment: Also, the steps in that mailing list thread don't seem to have a separate git origin repo, which I have, and seem to have B and C on separate machines, which is confusing to me.

Comment: @Harlan: B and C are on the same machine. As for the workaround, it is indeed after a `git-p4 clone`, not a `git clone`. Still, the idea remain: one initial import in a local git repo, made bare after that (B), and all the work done from C (cloned from B)