# Translation of Git -> Perforce fails

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I try to migrate a Git repository into Perforce. What I have tried is (e.g.)

1. Cloning `git clone https://github.com/mbostock/d3.git`
2. Changing directory to the new folder
3. Submitting with `git p4 submit`

This fails after a short while with the error message

```
fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD~1036
Command failed: git cat-file commit HEAD~1036
```

I haven't found a Git the migration works for. I am using Git 1.9.5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692884/git-p4-submit-fails-with-not-a-valid-object-name-head261

Comment: Thanks. But this question is not answering its question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git-p4 is really designed for cloning an existing p4 repo, and then mirroring that to/from git. You're trying to create a new p4 branch, which git-p4 can't directly do. So this is a little complex.

Try the following:

**1. Create an empty branch in p4 somewhere.**

You'll need a client pointed at your new location, //depot/foo:

```
$ p4 client whatever....
```

You will also need to create an empty file to keep p4 happy:

```
$ touch P4EMPTY
$ p4 -c your_client_name add P4EMPTY
$ p4 submit -d 'Add empty file'
```

**2. Clone it:**

```
$ cd /path/to/git/dir
$ git p4 clone //depot/foo
```

**3. Grab the repo you want to export:**

```
$ git remote add mycode git://whatever.git
$ git fetch mycode
$ git checkout -b upstream mycode/master
```

**4. Rebase it against the p4 repo:**

```
$ git p4 rebase p4/master
```

**5. Submit:**

```
# We don't want to edit the commit message, so skip that part
$ git config git-p4.skipSubmitEdit true
$ P4CLIENT=your_client_name git p4 submit
```

Or something like that anyway... :-)

Comment: Didn't work for me; the rebase gave the same error "Not a valid object name HEAD~43"

Answer (score 1):

Perforce's Git Fusion product enables Git repositories to be imported into Perforce.

Information about how to achieve this is located here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/chapter_dyn_ngj_3l.html#section_ecm_qdq_nj

Another advantage to using Git Fusion, is that user's don't need to install anything on their machines.

Hope this helps,
Jen!