# How to push a local Git repository to another computer?

Tags: git, git-push

I have a local Git repository setup on my laptop. I would like to push it to my desktop.

How can I do that?

Comment: git should be in superusers.com

Comment: Have you read the man page? typed `git help push`?

Comment: @vodkhang: no it should not be on superuser. It is an important part of a developer toolbox and his/her programming environment.

Comment: uhm, that can be right. I just thought because it relates to some administration stuff so it should be on that page:)

Comment: @vodkhang I asked some questions about git setup on serverfault.com too, but I think the real git users with best git knowledge are here.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you have access to a shared directory, you can (see [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) and [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)):

```
git clone --bare /path/to/your/laptop/repo /shared/path/to/desktop/repo.git
git remote add desktop  /shared/path/to/desktop/repo.git
```

That will create a [bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean), referenced in your local repo as "desktop".
Since it is bare, you can push to it (as well as pull from it if needed)

```
git push desktop
```

As the [ProGit book mentions](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html), git does support the file protocol:

> The most basic is the *Local* protocol, in which the remote repository is in another directory on disk.
>   This is often used if everyone on your team has access to a shared filesystem such as an NFS mount, or in the less likely case that everyone logs in to the same computer.

Comment: `git push desktop` means push `from` laptop `to` desktop. A `bare` repo is definitely not needed for this.

Comment: @Timo Yes, since 2015, a non-bare  repo is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030236/6309

Comment: What if I don't have access to a shared directory?  I'd like to do something like `git clone . ssh://user@desktop:git/remoteRepo.git` (from my local repo).  Or can this only be done by logging into my desktop and creating a (bare) repo there?

Comment: @AstroFloyd 8+ years later, you can use SSH, considering Windows 10 comes with a OpenSSH server (https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/heres-how-to-enable-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-client/, https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/how-to-install-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-server/)

Comment: @VonC no need for Windows here; OpenSSH has been around on Linux for ages.  However `git clone . ssh://user@desktop:git/remoteRepo.git` creates a local repo in a subdirectory called ssh:/user@desktop:git/remoteRepo.git whereas I'd like a *remote* repo - that's the whole point.  So how do I connect to the remote machine over ssh rather than creating a directory called ssh.

Comment: @AstroFloyd You did not mentioned your OS. And could you try the URL: `ssh://user@desktop/full/path/to/git/remoteRepo.git` (so no '`:`')

Comment: @VonC Sorry, using Linux locally and remotely.  That (full command being `git clone . ssh://user@desktop/home/user/path/to/git/remoteRepo.git`) creates a subdirectory tree `./ssh:/user@desktop/home/user/path/to/git/remoteRepo.git` in the current dir of my local box... :(

Comment: @AstroFloyd What version of git are you using? I assume that on the remote desktop, the path `/home/user/path/to/git/remoteRepo.git` does exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185285/discussion-between-astrofloyd-and-vonc).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a script that I wrote to do just this thing. The script handles all my usual initialization of new git repos

1. creates .gitignore file
2. initializes .git
3. creates the bare git repo on the server
4. sets up the local git repo to push to that remote repo

http://gist.github.com/410050

You'll definitely have to modify it to suit whatever setup you've got, especially if you're dealing with Windows laptop/desktop.

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create Git Repository
# created by Jim Kubicek, 2009
# jimkubicek@gmail.com
# http://jimkubicek.com

# DESCRIPTION
# Create remote git repository from existing project
# this script needs to be run from within the project directory

# This script has been created on OS X, so YMMV

#######
# Parameters
REPLOGIN=#Login name
REPADDRESS=#Repo address
REPLOCATION=/Users/Shared/Development #Repo location

# The repo name defaults to the name of the current directory.
# This regex will accept foldernames with letters and a period.
# You'll have to edit it if you've got anything else in your folder names.
REPNAME=`pwd | egrep -o "/[a-zA-Z]+$" | egrep -o "[a-zA-Z\.]+"`


# If you have standard files/directories to be ignored
# add them here
echo "Creating .gitignore"
echo 'build/' >> .gitignore # The build directory should be ignored for Xcode projs
echo '.DS_Store' >> .gitignore # A good idea on OS X

# Create the git repo
echo "Initializing the repo"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

# Copy the repo to the server
echo "Copying the git repo to the server $REPADDRESS"
TEMPREP="$REPNAME.git"
git clone --bare .git $TEMPREP
scp -r $TEMPREP $REPLOGIN@$REPADDRESS:$REPLOCATION/
rm -rf $TEMPREP

# Set up the origin for the project
echo "Linking current repository to remote repository"
git remote add origin $REPLOGIN@$REPADDRESS:$REPLOCATION/$REPNAME.git/
```

Comment: I would recommend copying your script in full in your answer (since it is not too big). Once Stack Overflow release the next cc-wiki dump (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), you are sure this script will *always* be available. Otherwise, +1

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (not the best) way is to share the repository directory via LAN, and use git's `file://` protocol (see `man git`).

For me, the best way is to use `gitolite` (see [gitolite docs](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/tree/master/doc/) for detailed instructions).