# Can I treat another git user as remote?

Tags: git

I want to push my commits to another git user (it is local development server that need t be a user not a git server) Is it possible to push to another git user? If yes then how?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to push to a non-bare repo? How can you access it?

Comment: I have 2 users (u1 and u2) with the same repo cloned (repo is on springloops). Can u1 push changes to u2 and u2 then to repo on springloops ?

Comment: Are both users on the same computer? If not, how can they access each other's repositories?

Comment: THey are in the same local network. I thought it can be managed via "remote" (got this option in smartgit)

Comment: Please see this: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. It talks about what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your user u1 can access the directory where u2's repo is, through a shared path, then:

- u2 can provide a bare repo by cloning repou2 as **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean)**.
  See for illustration [How to push a local git repository to another computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888029/how-to-push-a-local-git-repository-to-another-computer)

```
    # u2
    cd /path/to/parent/directory/of/repou2
    git clone --bare repou2 barerepou2
    cd /repou2
    git remote add barerepo ../barerepou2
```

- u1 can then add 'barerepou2' as a remote:

```
    git remote add repou2 /shared/path/to/u2/barerepo
```

- u1 can now push to u2 repo:

```
    git push repou2 master
```

- u2 can check from new contributions by u1

```
    git fetch barerepo
```

See "[Git push only for bare repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147741/git-push-only-for-bare-repositories)" on the importance of pushing to a bare repo instead of directly repou2 repo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to push to another user, its a push to a non bare repo, which is not preferred. You can do one of these to do the task.

- Push to a server and let everybody pull from there, like github.com
- Let the other guy pull from you. I would suggest this.

I hope this will solve the problem.