# how to push a existing android project to an organisation's repository?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I am working on Android studio and i wanted to push my android project to an organisation's repository but whenever i commit the changes it uploads the project to my username directory and not the Organisation's repository.
Please explain me by taking this example-
**my username**-*abc*
**organisation name**-*xyz*
**repository name**-*123*
so i want to upload my project to https://github.com/xyz/123

Comment: Check your remotes

Comment: Update you post with what exactly you have tried so far and the results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push a local Git repository to another computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888029/how-to-push-a-local-git-repository-to-another-computer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a new repository under your organization's account, then add it as a new remote:

```
git remote add newRemote https://github.com/organization/repo.git
```

Then, push using this command:

```
git push newRemote master
```

If you wish to make the organization's repo the default repo, you must replace the remote called `origin`:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/organization/repo.git
```

You can list all currently configured remotes like so:

```
git remote -v
```