# How do I add a remote Git repository to an Ubuntu Server?

Tags: git, ssh, repository, git-remote, ubuntu-server

I have created a Git repository on my Desktop machine (Windows 7) with:

```
git init
git add <all my files>
git commit -m "added my files"
```

Now I have installed a new Ubuntu Server 10.10 on a machine on my LAN and installed OpenSSH. My home directory is `/home/jonas` and I created a directory `~/code/` to contain my projects. I can log in to the Ubuntu Server from Windows 7 with Putty.

I installed Git on the server with `sudo apt-get install git`

### Adding a remote repository

Now I want to add my Git repository on my Desktop to the Server. I tried to follow the instructions from *Pragmatic Version Control Using Git*.

From my Desktop I run these commands:

```
git remote add origin jonas@192.168.1.10/home/jonas/code/myproject.git
git push origin master
```

But I got this error message:

```
fatal: 'jonas@192.168.1.180/home/jonas/code/myproject.git' does not appear to be
 a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**What is the problem? How do I create the remote repository?**

---

As PerfectlyNormal suggested, I added a `:` in the address. Now it worked better, and I had to type my password to the server, but then I got a similar error message:

```
fatal: '/home/jonas/code/myproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**Do I have to initialize a Git repository on the server before I can  `git push` to it?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Did you setup the repository on the remote server? You need to run

```
mkdir -p /home/jonas/code/myproject.git
cd /home/jonas/code/myproject.git
git init --bare
```

on the server in order to set it up. I recommend taking a look at how to setup a git server in the free [ProGit book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-2.html).

Comment: Thanks, this seem to work. But how can I checkout the project on the server? If I do `git status` then I get a message that I must be on a "work tree"

Comment: You can't. A remote repository must be a bare repository, which cannot be used for working on. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean/738256#738256) for more information. If you want to be able to work on the repo on the server as well, you need to checkout the repository in another directory on the server as well and use it just as if you were on a different computer (i.e. you must pull and push as usual).

Comment: @andrew-marshall Is that true? Couldn't he use a non-bare repo on the server and then push to `working-dir/.git`? Clearly, this is not a typical setup but isn't it possible?

Comment: It's _possible_ but will lead to unexpected results if you push to a branch on a remote repository that is checked-out on the remote machine. In fact, I don't think recent versions of git (1.7+ perhaps?) will even allow you to do so.

Comment: Pushing to the checked out branch in a non-bare repo is disabled by default. You can change the setting in every non-bare repo you create but its the default for a very good reason and unless you know exactly what you are doing you likely shouldn't even be attempting it.

Answer (score 49):

```
git remote add origin jonas@192.168.1.10/home/jonas/code/myproject.git
```

When using SSH, remote repository addresses can be expressed in two ways. One using absolute paths and one using relative paths from the users home directory. You've mixed them up.

The corrected command would be one of the following.

```
git remote add origin jonas@192.168.1.10:code/myproject.git
git remote add origin ssh://jonas@192.168.1.10/home/jonas/code/myproject.git
```

Comment: On a Mac, the format `jonas@192.168.1.10:code/myproject.git` worked!

Answer (score 8):

First thing I notice is that you're missing a ':'. Should be `git remote add origin jonas@192.168.1.10:/home/jonas/code/myproject.git`

Answer (score 3):

I normally create a bare repository locally and then scp that repository to the server when I'm setting up a remote repository.

For example,

```
cd c:\gits
git clone --bare c:\path\to\local\repository\some_project
```

which creates some_project.git.

Then,

```
scp -r some_project.git login@some.server:/path/to/remote/gits/.
```

enter your password or maybe you already have public/private key access working.

Comment: This creates a new repository on a remote server, without being 'there'.  Works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

you need a colon:

```
git remote add origin jonas@192.168.1.10/home/jonas/code/myproject.git
```

should be:

```
git remote add origin jonas@192.168.1.10:/home/jonas/code/myproject.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the handy script `git-create.bash`](https://gist.github.com/eikek/2203808) by [Eike Kettner](https://github.com/eikek)
. Give it your preferred remote address (`jonas@192.168.1.10:code/myproject.git`), and it will automatically SSH in to create the directory and initialize an empty `--bare` repository for you. All you need to do is add the `git remote` and `git push`.

> [`git-create.bash`](https://gist.github.com/eikek/2203808): Create new empty remote git repository via ssh

Usage:

```sh
git-create.bash 'jonas@192.168.1.10:code/myproject.git'
git remote add origin 'jonas@192.168.1.10:code/myproject.git'
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

> Connecting your Local Repo. to Git Remote Server Ubuntu
>
> Create a User in remote server and assign permission for ssh access using `ssh-keygen`
>   in your local server and paste, its `.pub` file to ssh of the remote
>   server.

**Things to do on remote Server**

Server : `XX.XXX.1XX.XX`

Inside Putty command line

1. Go to location : `cd ~/srv/git` srv in your root directory
2. Make a folder : mkdir your_file_name followed by cd inside your file **inside your git folder**
3. initialize git there : git init --bare

   ```
      Done
   ```

**Things to do On Local Machine**

1. create your repository ..
2. initializing Git: `git init`
3. Create the remote connection : `git remote add origin git@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/srv/git/your_file_name`
4. git push.

   ```
       Done
   ```

*If you got stuck any point refer :https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server.*