# GIT SSH Connection to server and create repository there and add files

Tags: windows, git, ssh, version

I need help with git.
I have a server, username and parol. I connect with ssh succesfully but i cannot add files. When i want add files (from my local pc) with bash using git add  it returing cannot find file path or path doesnot exist. I think it's searching files or directory in the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Git you don't create a repository directly on a server. Instead, you

- create a repository locally (`git init`),
- add files to it, which generally comprises two steps:

  - stage files (`git add`)
  - commit the staged files into the local repository (`git commit`)
- assign a remote server's repository to it (`git remote add`)

  - Note 1: I assume you have created a remote repository somehow - please refer to your server instructions.
  - Note 2: You create an empty repository on the server.
- upload your local repository to the remote one (`git push`)

Sample script:

```
$ cd your_local_project_dir/              # Get into your your project directory

$ git init                                # Initialize a local repository

$ git add --all                           # Stage all files from your local project
                                          # directory for commit (note this is not
                                          # adding to the repository yet, it's just
                                          # "prepare them to add into the repo")

$ git commit -m "Initial commit"          # Add the staged files to the local repository

$ git remote add origin https://server.com/user/project_name.git
                                          # Link the local repository to a remote one

$ git push -u origin master               # Upload you local repository data to the
                                          # remote one
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have done until add origin. I dont how i can do this. I have just ip adress server and username - parol for ssh connection.

Comment: @SamirAgcayev, you need to create an empty repository on that server. Is it a public server?

Comment: Then you have to establish an SSH session with that server and run three commands from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136451/4295017). Apparently, you've got to use your paths.