# Git - Pushing to Remote Repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local project source controlled with Git. I have a remote repo set up to point to a Dropbox directory(I know using Dropbox is not optimal but it's just easier for my particular circumstances). When I push changes to the remote repo I'm not seeing the files transfer.

There is only one branch, master. I've already added my changes with `git add .` , then I made the commit with `git -commit` . Then I tried to push to the remote repo using `git push -u origin master`. I get the message that things are compressing and being pushed but I don't see the changes in the directory. It's not an issue of Dropbox not syncing.I believe my remote is set up properly, when I use `git remote show origin` I get the following:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: /home/myuser/Dropbox/git/myproject.git/
  Push  URL: /home/myuser/Dropbox/git/myproject.git/
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

It seems to me that the status is saying that the remote repo is up to date but I don't see the changes. Could anyone suggest what I could be doing incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated, thanks much!

Comment: Are you pushing to a non-bare repo in Dropbox? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing changes into a remote repository just means that the remote repository has received the data; it won't be automatically checked out into the remote repo's working directory. VonC's comment on your question is almost certainly spot-on.